# Как парсить сайты с авторизацией?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Парсер с использованием Anglesharp.

Как парсить сайты с авторизацией?
Я пробую написать парсер.
Если я правильно понял теорию, то логика должна быть следующая:
- авторизация;
- получить куки;
Движение по страницам
- отправить куки;
- перейти на страницу_1;
- отправить куки;
- перейти на страницу_2;

Форма авторизации

```
<form name="login" class="ui large form" action="/login/" method="POST">
    <div class="required field ui grid aligned left"><input name="login[login]" value="" type="text" placeholder="Электронная почта" maxlength="64" autocomplete="off"></div>
    <div class="required field ui grid aligned left">
        <input name="login[password]" value="" type="password" maxlength="32" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Пароль">
    </div>
    <div class="equal width fields" style="flex-wrap:nowrap;">
        <div class="field" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="ui checkbox large step">
                <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="login[remember]" tabindex="0" value="1" class="hidden">
                <label for="remember">Запомнить меня</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="/forgot/">Забыли пароль?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <button class="fluid positive ui button big">Войти</button>
    </div>
    <input name="login[type]" type="hidden"><input name="login[init]" type="hidden" value="">
</form>
```

**Минимальный код**

```
public async void Authorization(string pathPageLogin, string userName, string password)
{
    IConfiguration config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCookies();
    IBrowsingContext browsingContext = BrowsingContext.New(config);

    browsingContext.OpenAsync(pathPageLogin).Wait();


    (browsingContext.Active.QuerySelector("input[name = 'login[login]']") as IHtmlInputElement).Value = userName;
    (browsingContext.Active.QuerySelector("input[name = 'login[password]']") as IHtmlInputElement).Value = password;
    (browsingContext.Active.QuerySelector("form") as IHtmlFormElement).SubmitAsync().Wait();


}

public async void Parsing(string url, string pathFileHtml)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url); // скачиваем страницу
    string source = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Переносим в переменную

    #region Сохранить страницу в файл
    File.WriteAllText(pathFileHtml, source);
    #endregion Сохранить страницу в файл

    #region Парсер
    // HTML парсер, который доступен из "AngleSharp".
    var domParser = new HtmlParser();

    // Спарсим асинхронно наш исходный код и получим документ с которым мы можем работать
     var document = await domParser.ParseAsync(source);

    // *** Парсер ****              
    // результат
    var list = new List<string>();

    var items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item =>
                item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("post__title_link"));

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        list.Add(item.TextContent);
    }
    #endregion

}
```

**Вопросы.**
1. Правильно ли я понимаю логику?
2. Как сделать код с минимальным набором основных методов для простых сайтов, чтобы было видно принцип логики?

**Дополнение**
Для примера использовать: rabota.by/login/

**Дополнение**
Логин - test9631@yandex.by
Пароль - Ym3LDp1FPs

**Дополнение**

Comment: Советую вам проверить, есть ли у сайта API, куда он при авторизации отправляет запросы, куда он отправляет запросы при получение контента и так далее. Очень часто бывает, что разбирать HTML совсем не обязательно!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дополнил вопрос. Если у вас есть возможность, не могли бы вы привести примеры кода как для приведённого сайта это может выглядеть. Я пробовал: собрал логирование, пробую проверить, залогинился или нет. Не получается. Где в браузере смотреть POST запросы знаю, но что от туда брать не понимаю... Вроде только логин и пароль отправляет... Хотелось бы на примере кода посмотреть. А то я уже начитался, насмотрелся.... Пробую реализовать, не получается..

Comment: Примеры кода мы привести не можем, так как нужны валидные логин и пароль. Вот что пишет при попытке регистрации: `Регистрация на сайте rabota.by доступна пользователям, находящимся на территории Республики Беларусь`. Пример [заполнения формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/830198/213987) уже был на сайте, да и у вас в вопросе практически готовый код, который осталось чуть допилить.

Comment: @AK Обновил вопрос. Добавил логин + пароль.

Comment: @AK `Пример заполнения формы уже был на сайте` - понимаю. Но не понимаю, как мне проверить залогинился  код или нет. Получил ли Куки.

Comment: @climivin Я вам ответом постарался рассказать как лучше поступить (правда пока не до конца), получите Cookie, получите полный доступ к ресурсу. К примеру вот [такой](https://hastebin.com/ulurewuram.pl) набор данных я получил по POST запросу на адрес `https://rabota.by/tradeslist/`. Другими словами у сайта есть API и вам стоит научиться с ним работать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не понимаю, как вы определили, что сайт имеет API? Я думал, что если сайт имеет API, то об этом пишется на самом сайте и  прилагается документация. PS. Прошу извинить если вопрос глупый, я пока осваиваю программирование. Спасибо за подробный ответ

Comment: @climivin Ну смотрите, раньше все сайты работали по принципу "пользователь зашел на страницу - сайт выдал дизайн с уже загруженными данными". Это не очень хорошо сказывалось на отзывчивости сайта, он был "топорным", постоянно обновлять страницу приходилось. Сейчас все современные сайты работают по принципу "пользователь зашел - загрузил дизайн без данных - часть нужных данных подгружается после, фоном". То есть сейчас идет разделение дизайна и данных сайта. Это позволяет сделать автоматическое обновление контента без перезагрузки страницы, сайт становится более отзывчивым и дружелюбным.

Comment: @climivin вот такие сайты создают себе источник данных, обычно это их внутренний API, о котором они не говорят, но мы же можем отловить эти запросы. Возьмем к примеру получение награды в игре. Пользователь видит кнопку и при клике на нее идет POST запрос допустим на адрес /api/getReward/ с помощью JS. Пользователю моментально, без обновления страницы, приходит уведомление об награде. Вот Вот при нажатие кнопки мы увидим в отладчике этот API запрос. Так что если сайт новый, то у него 80% есть API с которым и надо работать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Т.е. суть: отследить выполнение первого  `POST запроса с помощью JS` после нажатия кнопки. В нашем случае это `tradeslist/.` см. скирн `https://ibb.co/xGWXtsK`

Comment: @climivin Суть - отследить как именно сайт получает данные. Например вам надо получить список вакансий, вы запускаете отладку и заходите на нужную страницу и смотрите, что именно делает сайт. Если у него есть такой же, как `tradeslist/` адрес для получения этих данных, то супер, работайте с ним. На скрине вы смотрите на колонку инициализатора, а им может быть все что угодно. Смотрите на сам адрес и тип данных (обычно это `xhr`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Анализируем.**

Первым делом надо проанализировать сайт и понять как он работает. Я лично буду использовать [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) для отлова запросов, вы это можете делать там, где вам удобно...

И так, заходим на страницу авторизации, включаем отлов запросов, авторизуемся и смотрим на запросы.
Обычно они выглядят довольно заметно и идут на страницу вида `/login` или что то в этом духе.

После авторизации на сайте я поймал такой запрос:
[image: Result]

Смотрим сам запрос:

```
POST /login/ HTTP/1.1
Host: rabota.by
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 186
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://rabota.by
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.2.1388.37
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://rabota.by/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: sessionRabota=4t8r5v068lb7g9alo3; _ga=GA1.2.20569718.1545649; _gid=GA1.2.202925.15449; _ym_uid=15595112; _ym_d=154552; _ym_isad=1; _ym_visorc_2318=w; 388c2c03bbed9f4661; captcha=4509285; captcha_md5=59bf907333254603af10; arp_scroll_position=0; *0=*0
```

- Первым делом нас тут интересует тип запроса, у нас это `POST` на адрес `/login/`.
- Далее смотрим на тип передаваемых данных `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- Также может пригодиться `User-Agent` и некоторые `Cookie`.

Так, как у нас запрос с данными веб формы, то также стоит посмотреть его тело:

```
login[login]    user@mail.com
login[password] pass
login[remember] 1
submitButton    Войти
login[type] cad5afb6ed280bc4041d5689d561144a
```

Здесь все довольно понятно - наши логин, пароль, запоминать или нет, имя кнопки и неизвестный параметр с логина. Проверим этот неизвестный параметр, просто проделав авторизацию еще раз. Если он изменится, то стоит искать как он формируется, если нет, то можно использовать его. В моем случае он статичный.

Ну и еще стоит посмотреть сам ответ сервера, что он отдает и что он устанавливает:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: *0=%2A0; expires=Wed, 12-Dec-2018 19:21:31 GMT; Max-Age=-864000; path=/; domain=rabota.by
Set-Cookie: 666c9aea5601eb92b8=7df1b7318a82be0b068b; expires=Tue, 22-Jan-2019 19:21:32 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: d2c3f55839194555558=f33b13af8cfcd2d14c8650; expires=Tue, 22-Jan-2019 19:21:32 GMT; Max-Age=2678400; path=/; httponly
```

Видно, что в ответ сервер отдает нам обычный html и устанавливает пару Cookie. Тело ответа смотреть пока бессмысленно.

---

**Пробуем отправить запрос сами.**

Для этих целей отлично подходит [Postman](https://www.getpostman-beta.com). Устанавливаем, пропускаем авторизацию (или нет) и создаем новый запрос.

- Выбираем POST.
- Указываем адрес запроса `https://rabota.by/login`
- [вкладка Body] Указываем тип данных `x-www-form-urlencoded`
- [вкладка Body] Заполняем все поля запроса
- Пробуем отправить запрос.
- Смотрим данные (HTML). И видим там, что простой отправки данных нам не достаточно, сайт не авторизует нас. Что то не хватает. Обычно это либо заголовок UserAgent или какой то уникальный, либо Cookie.
- Пробуем добавить UserAgent - не подошел.
- Пробуем подобрать Cookie - и тут видим, что сайт наконец нас пустил (в HTML видим свои данные).

Теперь очистим запрос:

- Удаляем из Cookie по одному, пока не перестанет отправлять нам нужные данные. Я лично выяснил, что нужны всего одна Cookie - `*0=*0`.
- [вкладка Body] Тут по такому же принципу, убираем все не нужное, убирая просто галки. Мои наблюдения показывают, что достаточно всего лишь `login[login]`, `login[password]` и `login[type]`.
- [вкладка Headers] Убираем также лишние заголовки. На авторизацию влияют `Content-Type` и `Referer`.

[image: Postman]

Comment: Люблю я читать ваши ответы, прям подробные step-by-step туториалы для новичков.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Дополнил вопрос. Добавил логин + пароль.

Comment: @AK Спасибо, только пока продолжить не как не могу. Не получаются Cookie программно и все. Если найду решение, опубликую, нет, придется оставить так...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, если бы использовался HttpClient - для сохранения кук нужно было бы передать CookieContainer, в anglesharp скорее всего за это отвечает какое-нибудь свойство

Comment: @Grundy Я задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924312/220553), хотел получить только нужные "печеньки", в HttpClient, увы, не смог, правда я не помню, пробовал ли я всю коллекцию использовать). AngleSharp я не пользуюсь, так что как там - не знаю.