# Получить httponly cookie без домена

Tags: c#, cookie

Господа, недавно отвечал на [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и столкнулся с интересной особенностью.

Задача, получить Cookie с сайта после успешной отправки запроса.
Запрос отправляю следующим способом:

```
public async Task<string> Login(string login, string password)
{
    string data;
    var baseAddress = new Uri("https://rabota.by");

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login[login]", login),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login[password]", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("login[type]", "cad5afb6ed280bc4041d5689d561144a")
    });

    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("*0", "*0"));

    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer= baseAddress;

        var result = await client.PostAsync("/login/", content);
        var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).Cast<Cookie>();
        data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return data;
}
```

В результате в `var cookies` получаю не все "печеньки".
Запрос успешно отрабатывает, по HTML видны персональные данные, отлавливая ответ вижу, что Cookie успешно задаются, да вот только не отображаются в программе.

```
Set-Cookie: sessionRabota=4bq9aotr9a24897m8hk1jfo2k0; path=/
Set-Cookie: *0=%2A0; expires=Thu, 13-Dec-2018 00:30:11 GMT; Max-Age=-864000; path=/; domain=rabota.by
Set-Cookie: 666c9aea5601eb9d84c330a4f62012b8=7df1b7318a6c5c24327b8982be0b068b; expires=Fri, 23-Nov-2018 00:30:11 GMT; Max-Age=-2592000; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: d2c3f55b2a337c2bb0aa839194555558=62e5e4a2f71aeee4ca99a69a13496a71; expires=Fri, 23-Nov-2018 00:30:11 GMT; Max-Age=-2592000; path=/; httponly
```

Видим следующее:

- `sessionRabota` - устанавливается, без особых атрибутов. Она успешно ловится программой.
- `*0` - должна удалиться. В программе по прежнему есть.
- `не понятное название`(х2) - вот эти две Cookie видим пометку `httponly`, остальных отличий я не вижу. В программе, что бы я не делал - они не как не отображаются.

Вопрос: Как их получить программно?