# Есть ли разница установить отдельно куки, или установить заголовок с куки

Tags: c#, cookie, httpclient

у меня есть заголовки, в них есть `Set-Cookie: ....` и кучу cookies

И есть

```
IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).Cast<Cookie>();
            foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
            }
```

Который мне выдает 4 cookies

```
xman_us_f: x_l=0  по типу этого
```

Вопрос. `Set-Cookies` я должен устанавливать как заголовок, или я должен как-то от туда вытаскивать нужные мне cookies?

```
 string data;
            Uri url = new Uri("https://passport.aliexpress.com/newlogin/account/check.do?appName=aebuyer&fromSite=13");
            var baseAddress = new Uri("https://login.aliexpress.ru");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
            var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress };

            var result = await client.GetAsync(baseAddress);

            data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var head = result.Headers;

            foreach (var a in head)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.Key + ": " + a.Value.FirstOrDefault());
               // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(a.Key, a.Value.FirstOrDefault());
            }

            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).Cast<Cookie>();
            foreach (Cookie cookiew in responseCookies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cookiew.Name + ": " + cookiew.Value);
                cookieContainer.Add(cookiew);
            }
```

Comment: Куки, это куки, они хранятся в контейнере кук, заголовок же вам говорит, что сервер установил вам новую куку с такими то значениями.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Так а почему куки контейнер, не показывает эти куки, которые мне устанавливает сервер. Или как я понимаю, это идет все автоматически, а куки контейнер выдает другие куки, которые я уже сам вручную установить должен?

Comment: [Найдете ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924312/220553), дайте знать) Ну а так, некоторые Cookie имеют "защиту", они помечаются как `HttpOnly`, в теории, они должны быть в контейнере и если он используется 1 во всех запросах, то куки будут отправляться как надо, но тут я не уверен.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Получается он автоматически устанавливает куки, которые в заголовках, но куки контейнер не может их показать. Следовательно мне не нужно их устанавливать?

Comment: Я использую 1 контейнер, и отправляю 2 последовательных post, но контейнер их все равно не выдает, увы

Comment: добавь пример строки Set-Cookie которые не можешь получить, и пример как проверяешь. Ага, как проверяешь - вижу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ. локально у меня не воспроизводится ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy `Set-Cookie: ali_apache_id=10.182.213.149.1587672694661.406678.7; path=/; domain=.aliexpress.com; expires=Wed, 30-Nov-2084 01:01:01 GMT` только их там еще больше, это первый заголовок, т.к стоит у меня `Headers.Value.FirstOrDefault()`. В fiddler показывает дофига устанавливаемых куки, все они по идее отображаются в `Set-Cookie`, а в `cookiecontainer` меньше половины от всех

Comment: @PrinceTag, добавь это в сам вопрос

Comment: и как настраивал `HttpClient`: какой base address и путь запроса

Comment: есть подозрение, что дело в домене, который ты передаешь в `cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress)`

Comment: @Grundy Добавил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107113/discussion-between-grundy-and-prince-tag).

Comment: @Grundy Поискал аналогичные сайты, попал на сайт microsoft, у них тоже там есть подобные куки. Попробовав и выяснил, что проблема в `.`, которая располагается в начале и в том, что часть "кук" ставит сторонний запрос, который сайт делает в фоне. Поискав, выяснил, что уже давно есть [баг](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18597), взял [такой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15991071) код и вроде он отдает куки, где адрес указан через `.` в начале. Проверил на MS, отдал то, что необходимо, но не до конца уверен в данном решение, ибо вроде работает, а вроде через ж*. Но как вариант, да.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, заходи в чат, выше ссылка