# Как скачать картинку с сайта?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Я пытаюсь сделать парсер на основе "AngleSharp".
Я использую следующий код для скачивания:

```
var itemsAttr = document.QuerySelectorAll("img[id='print_user_photo']"); 
string foto_url = itemsAttr[0].GetAttribute("src");
string path = pathFolderIMG + id_source + ".jpg";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
webClient.DownloadFile(foto_url, path);
```

Для страниц "type_1" - [ссылка](https://rabota.by/resume/view/528089/) - код работает.
Для страниц "type_2" - [ссылка](https://rabota.by/resume/view/342239/) - код не работает.

Для "type_2" картинка находится по ссылке - [ссылка](https://rabota.by/userphoto/33318/46289/)

Как скачать фотографии для страниц "type_2"?

Comment: Вероятно, в вопросе следовало как-то акцентировать внимание на том, что "не работает" - это не значит "не находит на странице / не парсится", а что "не работает" - получаю 404 ошибку. В итоге я например сначала отвечал по сути не на тот вопрос, что вы хотели задать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я вижу, эти картинки имеют два адреса: первоначально грузится картинка в плохом качестве, а потом лениво грузится крупная картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну тогда так:

```
var img = document.QuerySelectorAll("img#print_user_photo").First();
//img.Attributes.Dump();
string foto_url = img.GetAttribute("data-pagespeed-lazy-src");
```

Но сайт отдаёт 404 в случае если реферрер пустой - видимо минимальная защита от скачивания. Делайте так:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("Referer",@"https://rabota.by/resume/view/342239/");
webClient.DownloadFile(foto_url, path);
```

Comment: Любопытно, что хотя ссылка нашлась именно та, что вы просили - но она не качается (404 Not Found) при помощи webClient - только из браузера. Видимо, стоит какая-то защита от скачивания, причём только для изображений с этого сервера? (Фото с ссылки type_1 скачалась без проблем) Но это видимо повод для другого вопроса.

Comment: Можно защиту обойти через взятие скриншота страницы и вырезание по позиции и размеру картинки на странице.

Comment: А еще можно открыть, например, CEF инстанс и сохранить страницу с разрешением ".png"

Comment: @Andrew Это как построить целый город ради одного бара. Не кажется лишним?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Кажется. Но иногда самое правильное решение - самое простое, даже если оно излишне дофига ресурсов жрет. Мы не знаем что за проэкт у парня. Может это какая-то однодневка и нужно не "правильное" решение, а быстрое решение. А то что я предложил - сработает как нужно и достаточно просто и быстро реализуется.

Comment: @A K **0.** По моему ваше решение дублирует мой вопрос. Т.е. у меня принцип тотоже: селектор + атриббут = получаю ссылку. Картинка не скачивается.
**1.** `(Фото с ссылки type_1 скачалась без проблем) Но это видимо повод для другого вопроса.` -  у меня как раз проблема со страницами "type_2". Буду признателен, если предложите решение по этому вопросу.
**2.** Я не нахожу аттрибут `"data-pagespeed-lazy-src"`. Не могли бы вы уточнить, где он находится? 
**3.** Какую программу вы используете? Т.е., что за программа у вас на картинке?

Comment: @Andrew **1.** `защиту обойти через взятие скриншота страницы` - не могли бы вы продемонтстрировать, полностью или кратко.
**2.** `можно открыть, например, CEF инстанс и сохранить страницу` - не могли бы вы продемонтстрировать, полностью или кратко.
**3.** `Мы не знаем что за проэкт у парня` - просто парсер для длительного использования

Comment: Наверное куки нужны

Comment: @eusataf 0 я прочитал ваш вопрос "не могу распарсить", возможно вам нужно более чётко формулировать вопрос, либо мне перестать читать so в полусонном состоянии. 1. [см. тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924219/213987) 2. см. img.Attributes - специально оставил в коде комментарий 3. linqpad, очень удобен для быстрого прототипирования

Comment: @eusataf Посмотрел, почему не качается. Сайт проверяет реферрер. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @A K Работает. `Посмотрел, почему не качается. Сайт проверяет реферрер` - если вам несложно, уточните как вы определили, что требуется  рефер?

Comment: @eusataf Нужно сравнивать запрос из браузера с отправляемым автоматикой и выискивать минимальный набор свойств, при которых для сайта нет разницы между ручными и автоматическими. Реферрер, заголовки и куки - это всегда нужно проверять в первую очередь при создании парсеров сайтов. За конкретной техникой снова отправлю к [этому замечательному ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924219/213987).

Comment: @eusataf 'ScreenshotAsync();' метод у CefOffscreen инстанса. если оно захватит больше чем даную картинку, то нужно еще при помощи js скрипта определить позицию и размер картинки ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633264/javascript-get-image-dimensions ). Но имей ввиду, мегабайт 50-100 оперативы оно пожрет только так. Ведь, это инстанс полноценного браузера.