# Авторизация средствами HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, winforms, httpclient

Не могу разобраться в авторизации.

Есть задача, пройти авторизацию на сайте passport.yandex.ru
Вроде бы задача простая и возможностей HttpClient должно хватить, но видимо я об этом классе не всё знаю.

Никак не могу авторизоваться.
Вроде передаю все параметры, все заголовки, а авторизация всё равно не проходит.

```
Cannot POST /auth/welcome
```

Насколько я понял, там отправляется не один POST запрос:

1. На проверку логина
2. На проверку пароля

Поведение у формы авторизации такое же, сначала ввод логина, а потом только появляется поле для пароля.

Но я так и не разобрался как это сделать правильно.

Может быть кто-то знает как пройти авторизацию на passport.yandex.ru

action ссылка:

[form method=post](https://passport.yandex.ru/auth?origin=home_desktop_ru&retpath=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.yandex.ru%2F%2F%3Fmsid%3D1553037660.31028.140515.134116%26m_pssp%3Ddomik)

P.S Авторизоваться на других сайтах у меня получается, там где отправляется 1 post запрос с параметрами login-pass.

Comment: И в чем трудности? Отправляете 2 запроса. 1. `POST /registration-validations/auth/multi_step/start` - данные `csrf_token`, `login`, `process_uuid`. Ответом получаете JSON, в теле которого будет `track_id`. 2. `POST /registration-validations/auth/multi_step/commit_password ` - данные `csrf_token`, `track_id`, `password`. В ответ получаете JSON со статусом и набор разных печенек. Вам остается найти `csrf_token`, `process_uuid` и какие Cookie отвечают за авторизацию. Мельком пробежавшись нашел все данные в HTML страницы (<body>). Так вопрос все же тот же, в чем трудности?

Comment: Технически я это понимаю, но в реализации не получается. Когда пытаюсь отправить POST на /start - ответ получаю код 403.

Comment: Я как то писал [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) ответ. Посмотрите, думаю будет полезно... Ну а так, найдите то, чего не хватает, отловите отправляемый вами запрос через `Fiddler` или его аналоги и посмотрите разницу.

Comment: Не составит труда попробовать на примере /start? хоть убей, не могу понять почему не проходит авторизация. через Postman тоже пытался, то же самое всё. Если конкретнее ошибку пишет - "Страница не найдена" - на /start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я вам покажу довольно простой пример проверки логина, пароль уже по аналогии сделаете сами..

И так, нам понадобится:

- Что то, с помощью чего будем разбирать JSON. Я выберу `Newtonsoft.Json`.
- Также нам понадобится брать некоторые данные из HTML, я возьму `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Теперь по порядку:

- Пробуем отправить запрос с помощью сторонних программ (`Postman`) и ищем то, что 100% необходимо отправить серверу. Об этом всем я писал в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) ответе.
- Не долго поиграв с запросом мы понимаем следующее:

  - **Тип**: `POST`
  - **Адрес**: `https://passport.yandex.ru/registration-validations/auth/multi_step/start`
  - **Тело**: `login` и `csrf_token`
  - **Cookie**: `yandexuid`
- Ищем где все эти значения находятся и видим следующее:

  - `login` - наш логин, задаем сами.
  - `csrf_token` - токен для защиты от "межсайтовой подделки запроса". Находится он в HTML, а именно в `body`, атрибут `data-csrf`.
  - `yandexuid` - как я понял это нечто на подобии идентификатора текущего сеанса. Его нам заносит сам сайт при первом посещении в Cookie.
- Теперь пробуем. Первым делом надо зайти на сам сайт и получить `csrf_token` и `yandexuid`. Что бы не использовать кортежи нам стоит создать простой класс с двумя свойствами:

  ```
  class LoginData
  {
      public LoginData(Cookie uid, string csrf)
      {
          Uid = uid;
          CSRF = csrf;
      }

      public Cookie Uid { get; set; }
      public string CSRF { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Делаем запрос:

  ```
  public async Task<LoginData> GetLoginData(string url = "/")
  {
      string data;
      var baseAddress = new Uri("https://passport.yandex.ru");
      var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
      using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = baseAddress})
      {
          var result = await client.GetAsync(url);
          data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
      var uidCookie = cookieContainer.GetCookies(baseAddress).Cast<Cookie>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "yandexuid");
      var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
      htmlDoc.LoadHtml(data);
      var csrf = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").GetAttributeValue("data-csrf", null);

      return new LoginData(uidCookie, csrf);
  }
  ```

  - Тут с помощью `HttpClient` мы будем отправлять Get запрос на основной сайт.
  - Через `handler` мы задаем `CookieContainer`, который будет содержать в себе установленные сайтом `Cookie`.
  - Далее мы отправляем Get запрос, получаем HTML, который заносим в `string data`.
  - Получаем все Cookie домена и находим нужную (`yandexuid`).
  - Работаем с HTML, ищем элемент `body` и забираем у него атрибут `data-csrf`.
  - Возвращаем в результате наш заполненный класс.
- Далее для удобства создадим простенький метод отправки POST запроса на сервер. Он будет принимать адрес, тело и Cookie c Uid. Ответом будет отдавать HTML:

  ```
  public async Task<string> SendPost(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent content = null, Cookie cookie = null)
  {
      string data;
      var baseAddress = new Uri("https://passport.yandex.ru");
      var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
      using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
      {
          if (cookie != null) cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
          var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
          data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      return data;
  }
  ```
- Ну что, остался метод для получения `TrackId`:

  ```
  public async Task<string> SendPost(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent content = null, Cookie cookie = null)
  {
      string data;
      var baseAddress = new Uri("https://passport.yandex.ru");
      var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
      using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
      {
          if (cookie != null) cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
          var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
          data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      return data;
  }
  ```

  - Мы получаем наши `LoginData`.
  - Составляем `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` тело с логином и `csrf`.
  - Вызываем метод для POST запроса, передав все необходимое.
  - Полученный результат (это JSON) мы преобразуем в JObject и отдаем `track_id`.
- Все, осталось вызывать метод `var trackId = await GetTrackId("login");`.

Вот такими довольно простыми действиями мы получили часть нужных нам данных. Остается сформировать запрос для проверки пароля. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё никак не мог разобраться с cookie. Большущее спасибо!