# Post и Get запросы

Tags: c#, winforms, http, httpclient

```
System.Net.Http
```

Как правильно формировать заголовки при обращении к сайтам с помощью `HttpClient` чтобы они показали документ такой же - как показывают браузеру ?

- Ведь если я какие то заголовки не укажу, он может показать какой то другой документ или вовсе выдать мне ошибку.

Я думал это делать вручную, указывая конкретные заголовки:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("", "");
```

Попытался разобраться глубже:

- Проверяю через браузер разные сайты и через консоль наблюдаю, что браузер использует абсолютно рандомные заголовки в запросе. Чего я руками точно не повторю.

Yandex:

```
Host: yandex.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: Были куки
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
TE: Trailers
```

Mail:

```
Host: limg.imgsmail.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://mail.ru/
```

Так вот как `HttpClient` может определять какие заголовки тому или иному сайту нужны и как это делает браузер ?

Если у меня будет 50 сайтов - не смогу же я под них заголовки руками повторять)

Comment: А что сайт может не так выдать вам? Отправляйте правильный `UserAgent`, `Referer`, да и все, 99% сайтов выдадут вам все. Остальные же заголовки нужны лишь в единичных случаях, например `Accept-Language` - некоторые сайты через него проверяют какой язык страницы ставить для пользователя, либо есть `Content-Type`, которые тоже некоторые сайты обрабатывают и через него можно получить html/xml/json и др. форматы данных. Есть еще `x` заголовки, которые тоже часто используются сайтами для передачи чего либо. Вообще, первоначально с браузера отправляется [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rYv5.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - оО - здорово что именно вы обратили внимание на этот вопрос, я как раз изучая HttpClient - учусь на ваших примерах) [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/237006) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959093/237006)

Проблема в том, что запихнув 50 сайтов, многие принудительно отклоняют `Get` запросы - не могу разобраться почему. Указываю `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0` и вот сайт для примера: [случайный)](https://anitokyo.tv/anime/504-ergo-proksi-ergo-proxy.html) браузеру доступный, `httpclient` выдаёт исключение.

Comment: Какую ошибку? Вот набросал за минуту пример, запустил и получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnDpU.png). Как видите даже без заголовков и чего либо еще мне выдало полный контент страницы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не могут же у меня при первом запросе к странице быть `Referer` и `Cookie` с помощью `HttpClient` - собственно как и у браузера. Что же тогда не пускает ? Перепробовал все заголовки кроме `Referer` и `Cookie` повторить - не пускает. Или для браузера при первом запросе к серверу он видит что нет `Cookie` и `Referer`, присваивает их и делает редирект чтобы проверить ?

Comment: `Cookie` используются в основном для авторизации, либо для защиты от подделки ответа. Предоставленный вами сайт не имеет чего либо. Я без понятия чего у вас там происходит, ибо как видите без заголовков и "печенек" сайт отдает мне контент. Вы кстати так и не сказали что за ошибка у вас. Ну а вообще, вы можете установить Fiddler и через него смотреть что отправляет ваше приложение и что отправляет браузер и так ищите виновника, ибо может у вас в браузере какое то расширение стоит для обхода блокировок каких то, может еще чего. Увы, я тут без заблокированного сайта вам помочь не смогу...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ пока писал) вы уже тест провели)
Вот мой пример - что не так) https://prnt.sc/q7jdip

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы виртуоз), действительно всё дело в расширении у браузера именно с этим сайтом, а я думал что то не так делаю(

Comment: @EvgeniyZ отключив расширение - выдал браузеру [https://prnt.sc/q7jgmv](https://prnt.sc/q7jgmv)

Comment: Ну тут либо у вас стоит блокировка у провайдера на данный сайт, либо у вас что то не так настроено, либо всеми любимый РКН старается (а он сейчас ох как за аниме взялся), либо у вас используется что то старое (браузер/в проекте старый .Net). Вот нарыл в интернете [информацию](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBarJ.png), может поможет. Ну а так, это индивидуальный случай, это не проблема в заголовках и запросах)