# Интеграция JavaScript в приложении

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser, интерпретатор

Мне нужно написать эмулятор браузера без GUI. Отправка запроса, парсинг страницы, взаимодействие с сайтом (нажатия на кнопки, ввод в поля), выполнение JavaScript и установка прокси.

Стандартный WebBrowser, WebKit, Gecko, CefSharp - не подходят, т.к. нельзя установить прокси для разных экземпляров. Selenium тоже не подойдет.

Как можно к своей программе прикрутить интерпретатор JS?

Или есть готовые проекты или полноценные браузеры на C#?

Comment: `Или есть готовые проекты или полноценные браузеры на C#?` - `HttpClient()`...

Comment: [Headless browser](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, HttpClient - далеко не браузер

Comment: а селениум почему не подходит?

Comment: @Grundy Дайте мне хоть один сайт, который требуется спарсить (а судя по вопросу автора это он и хочет) и для которого требуется тащить "тяжелую артиллерию" в виде селениума и прочей гадости, тогда соглашусь. Сейчас же как по мне автор совершенно не понимает что хочет сделать и пытается найти то, что за него сделает всю "магию", а он готовенькое будет собирать. Парс, это 99.9% банальный POST/GET запрос с нужными заголовками и куками, а это - `HttpClient()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, любое SPA или более менее сложный клиентский интерфейс и HttpClient - в пролете :)

Comment: @Grundy Повторюсь, дайте мне такой, я посмотрю из чего он состоит и я почти уверен, что найду там отправку запроса на некий адрес, который отдает ему данные для генерации.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, например rt.ru

Comment: @Grundy И что получать будем? Тарифы? Пожалуйста, [POST запрос](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWlmT.png), подберите только правильные параметры (заголовки/cookie) и получите чистый JSON с нужными данными. Нужно ли для этого тащить селениум? Не думаю... Я лично сделаю на чистом `HttpClient` без проблем. Вот к примеру я [авторизовался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/959093/220553) на сервисах яндекса, что позволило получить данные например почты и все на чистом c#.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104947/discussion-between-grundy-and-evgeniyz).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, для создания бота для сайта.

Comment: @CoollerFloyd Поймите как работает сайт, тогда уже и думайте, нужен вам целый браузер в проекте или нет. Я например без труда делал ботов для Web игр, где надо было тыкать периодически на разные кнопки для сбора лута и не поверите, все было на простом `HttpClient`. Повторюсь, большинство задач решаются банальной отправкой POST/GET запроса с нужными параметрами. Я соглашусь, да, есть задачи, где такой подход необходим, но их единицы и то, часть из них можно все же сделать на чистом C#, затратив больше времени на разработку.

Comment: Может кто-нибудь подсказать как установить прокси для WebBrowser? В инете есть несколько примеров как это сделать. Но они устанавливают общий прокси для всех экземпляров. Я думал может это можно сделать через рефлексию? Вскрыл dll через dnSpy и не могу найти где можно это сделать.