# WebClient.DownloadString ошибка JavaScript при попытке загрузки

Tags: c#, webclient

Я хочу считать содержимое файла с помощью `WebClient` по прямой ссылке на сайте, но при этом получаю в ответ это:

```
<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
            b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
            c = toNumbers("f6bae936aa0661846260ef14ec4e1934");
        document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        location.href = "URL файлу";
    </script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

Как я могу обойти это и всё-же загрузить содержимое файла?
P.S. Если пытаться скачивать не-текстовые файлы, то они скачиваются поврежденными.

Comment: У вас сайт четко намекает на то, что он свой контент берет извне. Не думали работать с источником данных, а не HTML?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ это ясно, но как это сделать? Я и так по факту даю ему прямую ссылку на файл, поэтому я не знаю, откуда он берет контент. Как это можно узнать?

Comment: Как отловить запросы я писал в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) ответе. Посмотрите и попробуйте на своем сайте это реализовать. Ну а вообще ваш сайт как видно по коду работает с Cookie, найдите ту, которая нужна и попробуйте отправлять вместе с запросом. Можете сам сайт предоставить, попробую поиграться на досуге...