# Ошибка 403 при авторизации на сайте PSN

Tags: c#, post, xnet

Отправляю POST запрос вылетает ошибка 403
Сниффер:Http analayzer
При обычной авторизации через браузер ошибок нет
Может что то не так сделал,помогите пожалуйста
Заранее спасибо
з.ы кто подскажет где ошибка

Проблема в том что по сниферу POST запрос отправляется на сайт
https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.do
Но как только я вызываю метод POST из библиотеке xnet то показывает ошибку 403
Как с этим бороться или я делаю что не так

```
using xNet;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SonyAuth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest())
            {
                //cookie & headers
                CookieDictionary cookies = new CookieDictionary();
                request.Cookies = cookies;
                request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=0");
                request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com");
                request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
                request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36");
                request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
                request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
                request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.Accept, "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
                request.AddHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
                request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.Referer, "https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.jsp");
                request.AddHeader(HttpHeader.AcceptLanguage, "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
                request.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;

                //search login_nonce
                string sourceCode = request.Get("https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.jsp").ToString();
                Match match = Regex.Match(sourceCode, "(?<=login_nonce\" value=\").*(?=\")");
                Console.WriteLine("login_nonce:\t" + match.Value);

                //request params
                RequestParams param = new RequestParams
                {
                    ["login_nonce"] = match.Value,
                    ["j_username"] = "email",
                    ["j_password"] = "password",
                    ["no_captcha"] = null
                };

                //push request & save to C:\\response.html
                HttpResponse response = request.Post("https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.do", param);
                using (StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter("C:\\response.html"))
                {
                    sWrite.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                    sWrite.Close();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Status code:\t" + response.StatusCode);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как парсить сайты с авторизацией?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Нет это не дубликат.

Comment: Нет, это дубликат. Если другой вопрос не копирует Ваш слово в слово, это ещё не значит, что Вы задали новый и уникальный вопрос. Там описана общая техника, причём исчерпывающая

Comment: Так в той теме не говорится про ошибку 403.Я повторил запрос точь в точь.Но в момент вызова метода POST,выбивает ошибку 403

Comment: 403 означает "Нет доступа". А его нет по той причине, что вы чего то не так отправляете серверу. И о том как найти то, что нужно отравлять и как это все отладить я описал в том вопросе. Например я вижу целую [портянку Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6daQ.png), которые отправляются от вас к серверу.  Вы уверены, что все эти Cookie у вас есть? Я также не уверен, что вы отправляете именно application/x-www-form-urlencoded на сервер. Не пишите сразу код, сделайте запрос в Postman, удалите из него все лишнее, а уж потом пишите запрос программно, смотря что ваша программа отправляет через Fiddler

Comment: Так,я понял,пойду тестить.Спасибо за совет.Если будут вопросы сюда напишу.Пасиб еще раз

Comment: Попробовал через Postman аналогично 403 ошибка хотя при том что заголовки и параметры были идентичны запросу браузера.Покопаюсь еще ,вдруг получиться