# xamarin + css авторизация

Tags: xamarin.forms

Нужна ваша помощь ребят. Я хочу реализовать авторизацию с xamarin forms приложения, мне нужно обращаться на сайт, а именно к css скрипту на нём, который отвечает за авторизацию, какие есть идеи для реализации этого? Буду сильно благодарен помощи.

Comment: css автортзация??

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что за авторизацию на сайте отвечает не php скрипт, а css.

Comment: css - это стили, они не отвечают за авторизацию. Вы уверены в том, о чем говорите?

Comment: Не уверен, можете узнать ссылку на авторизацию? Мне нужно для запроса на сайт. https://www.oat.ru/user (не реклама)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть такая возможность?

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), вам должно этого по сути хватить для понимания. Правда с капчей я без понятия что вам делать.