# post multipart C# image httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, post, instagram, multipart

Прошу помощи, пытаюсь отправить post multipart запрос с картинкой, отправляю в инстаграм для смены аватарки. Ответ от сервера правильный, такой же как и при изменении аватарки с браузера, вот только программа меняет аватарку на пустую, при сравнении запросов в браузере и в программе видно что в том месте где должна быть картинка, те между границами(boundary) текст короче в программе, в браузере Content-Length    102920 в программе Content-Length: 17402.

```
string updateava()
{
    string boundary = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\kartinki\Famous Numbers - Euler Constant.JPG");

    textBox1.Text = bytes.Length.ToString();

    string data = "-----------------------------" + boundary + "\n" + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_pic\"; filename=\"profilepic.jpg\" +\n" + "Content-Type: image/jpeg \n \n";
    string dataend = $"\n-----------------------------{boundary}--";
    byte[] Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] Dataend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataend);
    //https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/
    string site = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_change_profile_picture/";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(site);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Accept = "*/*";
    request.ContentLength = Data.Length+Dataend.Length+bytes.Length;
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------" + boundary;

    request.Headers.Add("Origin: https://www.instagram.com");
    request.Headers.Add("TE: Trailers");

    request.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/";
    request.Headers.Add("accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br");
    request.Headers.Add("accept-language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    request.Headers.Add("DNT: 1");
    request.Headers.Add($"cookie: {defaultcookie}");
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.All;
    request.Headers.Add("X-IG-WWW-Claim: 0");
    request.Headers.Add($"X-IG-App-ID: {Gxigappid}");
    request.Headers.Add($"X-Instagram-AJAX: {Gxinstagramajax}");
    request.Headers.Add($"X-CSRFToken: {xcsrftokens}");
    request.Headers.Add($"X-IG-WWW-Claim: {xigsetwwwclaim}");
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25";

    using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //stream.Write(bytes);
        stream.Write(Dataend, 0, Dataend.Length);

    }


    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string header = response.Headers.ToString();
            string responsestr = stream.ReadToEnd();
            string Path1 = @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\C#\7.txt";
            using (StreamWriter stream1 = new StreamWriter(Path1, true))
            {
                stream1.WriteLine(header);
                stream1.WriteLine("");
                stream1.WriteLine(responsestr);
            }
        }
    }


    return "";
}
```

В запросах, в месте где картинка, дикие крякозябры (Это с браузера, начальный кусочек)

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_pic"; filename="profilepic.jpg"
Content-Type: image/png
PNG

���
IHDR��g��g���]ÐcF���sRGB�®Îé���gAMA��±üa��� pHYs��Ã��ÃÇo¨d��ÿ¥IDATx^ì½ ^E¹î?³ê×wïõÛ_Ý½÷^ÒH t¤£à(*¨ØÀ£H=½P¤  *  U ´ÐHB
é¢sÏ½ÿ{
ÿÏ;3ûË.IÜvÈNæÉÚó­5kfÖ¬Yï3ïªLsPÂ5ÎUo!¨Jk406lPýUs¡ö°æÐFõª´Fs�£Uó EíaÍ¡ê
3Uiæ�F«æAÚÃCÕfªÒÍVÍµ56ª7ÌT¥5­-jkmTo!¨Jk40Z5ZÔÖÚ¨Þ0CPÖh`´j´¨=¬9´Q½a *­ÑÀhÕ©¨¨ÑÌTÇ~TyÍô Us¦¢v F3CPwúQåi4ÓVÍÚÍAuÜéG§ÑLZ5g*jj43Õq§UF3=hÕ©¨¨ÑÌTÇ~TyÍô Us¦¢v F3CPwúQåi4ÓVÍÚÍAuÜéG§ÑLZ5tÔÒhf8ªCOB-Z6eÔjP÷J§ÑL­:jGi43Õ¡'¡G-2jµñ¨e{E%Õh¦VÍµ£4êÐPÇ£MµÚxÔ²½¢
```

Comment: Во первых, прекратите использовать `HttpWebRequest`, он [устарел](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest)! Во вторых, вы делаете очень много лишнего, я на 100% уверен, что 90% заголовков, которые вы шлете - банальный мусор, выделите только необходимые данные и их отправляйте (об этом я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553)). У вас должно быть нечто, похожее на [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983672). Ну и напоследок, почему не API? Сейчас у вас костыль...

Comment: А разве картинки не нужно перед отправной преобразовывать в `Base64`?