# Как кликать на кнопки, и заполнять поля c#

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Есть такие парсеры как htmagilitypack и anglesharp, на них я научился парсить данные, но не могу найти ответа, как наживать на кнопки, и заполнять поля для воода(по типу логина и пароля). Если есть примеры кода(если не сложно, объясните как и что делает) или ссылки которые могут помочь с ответом, скиньте их пожалуйста. Если есть реализации с мощью других парсеров, тоже подойдет,но кроме Selenium/Selenide.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553

Comment: А без куки не как нельзя?

Comment: Если авторизация, то это куки, либо токен. Хотите ее, будете использовать куки, что бы вы не использовали (хоть селениум).

Comment: Ну, селениум работает по методам, там не нужно отлавливать куки. Вас понял, на кнопки нажимать любые, тоже куки?

Comment: Селениум это делает за вас, вы можете без труда их получить. Просто селениум это браузер, который имеет свой API, не более. Любая кнопка на сайте - это запрос куда-то (POST/GET), отловите его и смотрите что требуется. Если у вас простой переход на следующую страницу, то не думаю, что там нужны куки, если же это редактирование данных некого пользователя, то нужны, ибо через них сервер понимает, что это вы, а не Вася Пупкин, который вдруг вздумал изменить вам пароль.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.