# У меня есть спарсенный сайт с Js

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

Я спарсил сайт и js тоже, теперь как мне подключить мой спаресенный string, чтобы anglesharp проанализировал его и нашел нужные мне теги, вот код парсинга:

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"...");
            req.Method = "POST";
            //Вот тут пришлось погуглить так как не редко тип у каждого свой, в итоге нашел в одном из проектов на github.
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-urlencoded";
            string str = "";
            WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
            using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream()) //Пишем в поток.
            {
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(s)) //Читаем из потока.
                {
                    str = r.ReadToEnd(); //!!!Изменения
                }
            }
            response.Close();
```

Как подключить его к anglesharp теперь? Нужен код, если нету такой возможности, то покажите на чем другом можно реализовать

Comment: При чем тут JS, какие теги? Может ваша задача вовсе решается по другому? Тогда давайте сайт, будем смотреть что и как.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/p/B8qYU66g2rh/ вот ссылка на инстаграм, я хочу спарсить комментарии с поста, но как-то обычным html не поулчается, вот сейчас я поулчил json(js) данные в string, как мне заставить anglesharp работать с ними?

Comment: JSON и JS - две совершенно разные вещи. По поводу вопроса - во первых, `WebRequest` является устаревшим классом (посмотрите в документации его аналог), во вторых поймите для начала как работает необходимый вам сайт, конкретно в вашем случае вообще не нужен HTML парсер (`HAP` и `AngleSharp`), ибо сайт отдает все данные в открытую, достаточно добавить всего навсего `?__a=1` в конце запроса. Вот например [ваши комментарии](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoRb9.png). Так у меня вопрос тот же, при чем тут JS?)

Comment: Я все время работ с селенайдом и не задумывался как сайты работают, сейчас мне понадобилось парсить сайты через коносль, и вот я пытаюсь научиться

Comment: Я хочу именно программно взять ссылку с елемента. Как я могу это сделать? Взять как текст и сравниванием строк делать?

Comment: Просто если я буду работать с подобными сайтами, я мог знать алгорит и сделать так же

Comment: Если добавить эти символы в конце, то можно спарсить как html получается... Но если есть подгрузки и тп, то моим способом наверное лучше будет работать. Можете конкретно сказать на чем парсить подобные сайты, и как брать информацию?

Comment: Сайт дает вам полный JSON указанной страницы, берите из него все, что надо, а лучше используйте API, если сайт его имеет. Как парсить другие сайты - смотрите например [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) ответ.