# Ошибка при Get-запросе C#

Tags: c#, get, request

При get запросе в response получаю вот такую строку:

```
{"error":"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound"}
```

Итак,хотелось сделать авторизацию на сайте.Для начала отправляю get-запрос с параметрами:

```
.com/ajax.php?c=account&a=dologin&email=1234%40gmail.com&password=1234
```

и обратно получаю строку:

```
{"MemberID":"8860655","LoginKey":"6227a05b8d53e4892789979eb35a859c"}
```

Вторым запросом отправляю эти параметры:
.com/ajax.php?c=account&a=init&key=4993d19856e0abcdc1451ef845d23a3d&mid=8860655
и получаю ошибку ,описанную выше.

Если поменяю ключ на рандомный,то просто получу сообщение о том,что сессии нет:

```
{"error":"No valid session for 307c3c239ba3813f03e8f1f0159df9a1"}
```

```
 private static string GET(string URL, string Data)
        {
            System.Net.WebRequest Req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL + "?" + Data);
            System.Net.WebResponse Res = Req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream Stream = Resp.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Stream);
            string Out = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            Reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(Out);
            return Out;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Key = GET(".com/ajax.php","c=account&a=dologin&email=1234@gmail.com&password=1234");
            string ID = Str.Inside(Key, "\"MemberID\":\"", "\",");
            Key= Str.Inside(Key, "\"LoginKey\":\"", "\"}");
            Key = "c=account&a=init&key=" + Key+ "&mid=" + ID;
            GET(".com/ajax.php", Key);
        }
```

Comment: Простите, а как мы можем вам тут помочь? Каждый сайт работает по разному и просит разные данные, разными способами. Вы же говорите "Получаю ошибку", не предоставив нам данных, с которыми мы могли бы работать. Давайте минимальный, самодостаточный пример и будем тогда думать, сейчас же вам вряд-ли кто сможет дать адекватный ответ, ибо это гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Совсем забыл прикрепить сайт,виноват.Вот для примера https://www.thesimsresource.com/account/login

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я пытался отследить через консоль crome и понять,как это работает,но не особо помогло)

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней на запрос, который ваш браузер отлавливает, хотяб на первый, что вы там видите помимо заголовков и самого запроса? Дам очень жирную [подсказку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y5oq.png). Ну а вообще, посмотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), там я про все подобное писал. Также хочу заметить, что вы используете старый класс для работы с Web, стоит для новых разработок переходить уже на `HttpClient`, да и в нем попроще и приятней все это будет выглядеть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Огромное спасибо,буду учиться)