# Как парсить информацию с сайтов которая динамически подгружается?

Tags: python, парсер

Мне нужно собирать информацию о всех предметах,пример сайта:
https://loot.farm/en/
Но проблема в том что предметы подгружаются по мере того как вы скроллите вниз.
Как в таком случае парсить все предметы?Какой способ самый быстрый и удобный и есть ли он вообще?)

Comment: Работайте с [сервером](https://loot.farm/botsInventory_730.json). Думаю также поможет [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553). Также там работа идет через вебсокет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а про сервер,что это и главное откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: То, что вы видите как пользователь сайта - это всего на всего удобный для вас UI (интерфейс), простой набор кнопочек и прочих элементов, которые помогают вам общаться с сервером. Сам же сервер, это набор команд (API), который принимает их через POST/GET и др. запросы на определенный адрес. Вот именно эти запросы вам и надо искать и через них общаться с сервером напрямую, без парса HTML и другой ерунды. Где взял? Ну, я вам дал ссылку выше на мой ответ, где подробно это объяснял, ну а так, F12 в браузере, вкладка "сеть", там увидите этот JSON, который просит сайт у сервера.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в том json далеко не вся информация что нужна,например там нет цены.

Comment: Ну так я вам дал лишь направление, а все нужное ищите уже сами. Запрос, конечно, может быть не один, также не забывайте, что там есть WebSocket соединение, которое тоже в реальном времени подгружает данные. Ищите)