# При попытке получить HTML страницы возвращается пустая строка

Tags: c#, html, httpclient

Пытаюсь получить HTML страницы: `https://minsk.btrans.by/avtobus/1%d1%82` или же `https://minsk.btrans.by/avtobus/1т` через HttpClient.GetAsync, но в ресультате пустая строка, хотя при попытке получить HTML с данной страницы:`https://minsk.btrans.by/avtobus/1` все удается

HTMLAgilityPack пробовал, но результат тот: не парсит контретно с этой страницы

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://minsk.btrans.by/avtobus/1%d1%82";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `client.GetAsync(url).Result` - серьезно? Забудьте про написание сразу запроса кодом! Займитесь анализом сайта, поймите как он устроен, как у него появляются данные, от куда он их берет, попробуйте составить запрос в любом конструкторе (Postman например), а вот когда получите в конструкторе готовый, рабочий запрос, без кучи лишнего, тогда уже и думайте про написание C# кода. [Почитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553)...

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(response);` поможет узнать, что ответил сервер

Comment: Я как бы нашел проблему, `HttpClient` оправляет запрос `/avtobus/1%D1%82`, и получает 302 редирект на `/avtobus/1%d1%82`, но не следует ему. Проблема кроется внутри класса `Uri`, но я не могу понять, как ее побороть. @EvgeniyZ задача интересная, есть идеи? Как бы я не пытался подсунуть разные данные даже через рефлексию в инстанс `Uri`, у меня ничего не вышло (замена поля `_string` портит `Uri`). Если кратко, `Uri` парсит `1%d1%82` как `1т` при создании инстанса, а в запрос отдает `/avtobus/1%D1%82`. Какая-то фишка дотнета, побороть которую мне не удалось.

Comment: @aepot Бился с этим 2+ часа, решение тоже не нашел. Тут проблема больше в сайте, чем в фреймворке. Сайт требует именно нижний регистр, иначе, редирект. C# следует всем правилам и конвертирует текст так, как положено, но увы... В итоге там цикличный редирект идет. Интересный факт, если написать `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("https://minsk.btrans.by/avtobus/15д");`, выдаст строку в нижнем регистре, но `Uri` поправит. Попробовал `new Uri(address, true)` (хоть он устарел, но всеж), передал ему результат `UrlPathEncode`, но `Uri` не все поля заполнил. Пробовал через билдер, не дало результат.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ понял, попробую сегодня еще поковырять. То что сайт странно себя ведет - факт. Но в браузерах же работает, а это значит что дотнет надо фиксить.

Comment: @aepot буду признателен если найдете способ как это починить или обойти. Попробовал отправить запрос с помощью Fiddler и все работает, так что это скорее всего бага дотнета

Comment: Это скорее баг сервера, а не дотнета. То что дотнет обладает меньшей толерантностью к такого рода косякам - это не баг дотнета. Но дотнет можно пофиксить до уровня браузера. Выставление багов в dotent/runtime - штука не простая, фикс тоже может ехать очень долго, то есть в .NET 7 например только успеет. Поэтому самое простое решение - это таки найти лазейку, вплоть до низкоуровневой отправки запросов через сокеты. Я еще поковыряю этот вопрос, но позднее.