# Не скачивается .pdf файл

Tags: c#, download

Обычные картинки нормально скачиваются, а он битый получается.
Вот ссылка на файл `https://www.margroid.ru/upload/fitting.pdf`

Вот это код:

```
string image = link;
string konec1 = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf("."), image.Length - image.LastIndexOf("."));
if (!image.Contains("http"))
   image = host + image;

Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Work\{sitename}\" + NA);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(image), $@"C:\Work\{sitename}\" + NA + @"\" + number_image + konec1);
}

string gg = $"/upload/staff/upload/staff/{sitename}/" + NA + "/" + number_image + konec1 + ";\r\n";
number_image++;
return gg;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Внимательно посмотрите то, что вам отдает сайт, он отдает PDF? Или он отдает например [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMxm.png)? А почему он это отдает? Наверно потому, что нет определенных параметров? Например Cookie? [Проанализируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) сайт, научитесь понимать что он делает, а не бездумно выполняйте то, что вы хотите. И да, советую найти документацию по `WebClient` и увидеть нам "Не рекомендуется использовать для новой разработки", то есть `WebClient` устарел!

Comment: У меня куки стоит, я же говорю, картинки нормально качаются, пдф, нет. Картиинки тоже требуют куки

Comment: Где? Я в коде их не вижу. Какие? Что анализатор трафика показывает?

Comment: Там нужен 1 кукис `ddos_guard_flag=true;`

Comment: А где ваш await? Вы уничтожаете WebClient до того, как загрузка закончится.

Comment: @VladD `DownloadFileAsync` - это `void`

Comment: Студия выдает ошибку с await. Но тут это не  важно, можно метод на обычный DownloadFile заменить, рузльтат тот же. Битый pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пользуетесь асинхронной функцией [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-5.0), которая не выполняет до конца, а лишь инициирует загрузку. Сразу после этого ваш код выходит из блока `using` и уничтожает `WebClient`, который производит загрузку в фоновом режиме, вот файл и получается недогруженный.

Если для маленьких файлов ваш `WebClient` *иногда* успевает загрузить весь файл, то для больших происходят очевидные проблемы.

Возможные решения:

1. Дождитесь окончания загрузки, подписавшись на `DownloadFileCompleted`, и только по приходу этого события уничтожайте `client`.
2. Сделайте ваш метод асинхронным (`async`), воспользуйтесь более современной функцией `DownloadFileTaskAsync`: `await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...);`
3. Если очень не хочется работать с асинхронными функциями, воспользуйтесь синхронным методом `DownloadFile(...)`, но если вы в UI-потоке, приготовьтесь к подвисаниям.

Я бы рекомендовал альтернативу 2. Ещё можно перейти с давно устаревшего `WebClient` на современный [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0) (он весь асинхронный), и использовать что-то наподобие

```
var sourceStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(new Uri(image));
using (var targetStream = File.Create($@"C:\Work\ ..."))
    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
```