# Парсинг динамической страницы

Tags: c#

Необходимо получить со страницы https://bago.si/club (сайт безопасен) получить id последней созданной группы Вк. Если просмотреть исходный код страницы, то в нем нет искомой ссылки. Не очень понимаю, почему так происходит. Возможно ли в данном случае распарсить страницу? Если да, то как? Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, при этом Fidler не может показать содержимое запроса, т.к. есть шифрование...

Comment: О каком шифровании идет речь? Https? Fiddler умеет их "расшифровывать".

Comment: Жутко туплю к ночи. Запрос - POST /api/vk.getLatestGroup?hash=51827a9e HTTP/1.1. Существуют ли способы выяснить, на основе чего создается hash? Для работы с вк необходим токен, но не факт, что он именно здесь передается...

Comment: Можно и без фидлера обойтись. Сетевой трафик можно увидеть на вкладке Сеть в инструментах разработчика прямо в браузере.

Comment: @aepot, да, но вопрос все равно в хэше, который передается с запросом

Comment: `Существуют ли способы выяснить, на основе чего создается hash?` - открываете поиск (фиддлер и что либо еще), пишете там `51827a9e` и смотрите кто вам его первый выдал и от куда он его взял. Значения просто так с потолка не появляются...

Comment: Здесь 2 варианта, либо оно было передано в браузер с одним из ответов, либо сгенерено локально яваскриптом. Задача реверс-инжениринга - творческая и требует навыков. Тренируйтесь, ищите. Готового ответа на ваш вопрос нет.