# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: "element not interactable (С#) Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Код:

```
private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        string steamguard = textBox3.Text;

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live%2Fauth%2Fv1%2Fcallback%2Fsteam%2F901e7d34-06c1-44b0-82b4-2f982c058361");
        
        IWebElement log = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamAccountName\"]"));
        IWebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamPassword\"]"));
        IWebElement sign = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"imageLogin\"]"));
        IWebElement sguard = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"login_twofactor_authcode_entry\"]/div"));     

        log.SendKeys(login);
        pass.SendKeys(password);
        sign.Click();
        sguard.SendKeys(steamguard);
  }
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Программа почему то не может ввести текст в строку и выдает ошибку;
Как можно решить эту проблему. Спасибо).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался решить проблему:

```
  private void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string login = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        string steamguard = textBox3.Text;

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.realm=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.dmarket.live%2Fauth%2Fv1%2Fcallback%2Fsteam%2F901e7d34-06c1-44b0-82b4-2f982c058361");
        
        IWebElement log = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamAccountName\"]"));
        IWebElement pass = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"steamPassword\"]"));
        IWebElement sign = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"imageLogin\"]"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement sguard = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"twofactorcode_entry\"]")));

        log.SendKeys(login); 
        pass.SendKeys(password);
        sign.Click();
        sguard.SendKeys(steamguard);  
}
```

Но не помогло.

Comment: Вот можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам тут вообще селениум? Вы тестируете сайт или что? Для стима есть куча готовых решений, библиотек, которые умеют в 2fa, также стим весьма открыт в плане простых запросов.

Comment: Возможно селениум и не нужен. Не подскажите, что можно прочитать для автоматической авторизации на сайте.

Comment: Зависит от того, какие возможности вам нужны, что именно вы хотите получить. У стима есть API, часть функционала там открытая, часть требует API ключ. Если этого вам мало, то для C# есть `SteamKit`, который очень многое умеет (вот например ваш [SteamGuard](https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/blob/master/Samples/5.SteamGuard/Program.cs)). Если и этого мало, то отлавливайте [запросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) и повторяйте их в программе. И помните, селениум это QA (тестирование), а не автоматизация!

Comment: Мне просто нужно авторизоваться на сайте https://dmarket.com/ru.

Comment: Я вам советую использовать простую авторизацию по логину и паролю, авторизация через стим (или другие соц. сети)) весьма геморная бывает.

Comment: Дело в том, что этот сайт поддерживает только авторизацию через стим.

Comment: А [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf29Y.png) что? Простая форма, даже API авторизации у сайта [есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyXnZ.png). Осталось разобраться что именно он требует (ссылка выше) и отправить это через простой `HttpClient`. Правда там ReCaptcha, с ней ух какие проблемы могут быть, но благо сайт просит ее не всегда.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как бы `div` не умеет сам по себе принимать ввод.

Ввод надо отправлять в `input`, который может выглядеть примерно вот так:

```html
<input type="text" name="code">
```

Он скорее всего расположен внутри того самого `div`, на который вы указали.

Comment: Я поменял на IWebElement sguard = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"twofactorcode_entry\"]"));  но ошибка не исчезла.

Comment: @human03289 это пока не значит, что мой ответ неправильный. Убедитесь, что `sguard` содержит именно тот инпут, который вы запросили.