# C# AngleSharp проблема с получением непосредственно дочерних элементов

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Есть ряд вопросов, которые не могу решить уже часа 2, буду благодарен за помощь.

(Для примера буду использовать следующий url для парса https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE)

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var address = "https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BE";
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = context.OpenAsync(address).Result;
```

1. Хочу получить элемент

> div.vector-body#bodyContent

[image: Режим разработчика любого браузера с легкостью находит его]

Режим разработчика любого браузера с легкостью находит его, но следующая строчка кода вернет мне null:

`return document?.QuerySelector("div.vector-body#bodyContent") == null; //true`

В чем может быть проблема? Что я делаю не так? Я, конечно, понимаю, что могу получить этот элемент другим способом, но что с этим не так?

2. Основной вопрос:
   Хочу получить количество непосредственно дочерних элементов (находящихся на глубине 1) узла

> div.mw-parser-output > *

Браузер правильно сообщает, что элементов 42:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот следующая строка кода вернет 3:

`return document?.QuerySelectorAll("div.mw-parser-output > *").Length; //Возвращает 3`

Буду рад каждому ответу, спасибо.

Comment: Наверное содержимое страницы приезжает не в основном запросе, а в AJAX уже после того как страница загружена, и элемент, который вы ищете добавляется на страницу яваскриптом. Смотрите вкладку Сеть в инструментах рахработчика в браузере, там весь трафик и данные. Попробуйте для теста `Console.WriteLine(await new HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://url"));`. Не забудьте у метода `void` поменять на `async Task`, чтобы сделать его асинхронным и использовать `await`. Никогда не используйте `.Result`.

Comment: Запомните одно простое правило: не берите за основу те данные, что видите в браузере! Почему? Да потому, что очень часто они отличаются от оригинала, ведь сайт потом запускает JS или другую логику, которая меняет содержимое страницы. Напишите в вашем коде `document.ToHtml().Contains("vector-body");`, что выдаст? Вот простейший [тест](https://dotnetfiddle.net/27Vo4g). Что касается "возвращает 3", тоже, смотрим [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h9Jp.png).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое, немного прояснился в этом вопросе. Но проблема осталась, как мне тогда парсить страницу, если нужных мне узлов нет при использовании `document.QuerySelectorAll`?

Comment: @hlooo Вы меня наверно не услышали. Я вам сказал "Не берите за основу те данные, что в браузере". Это значит что? Правильно, берете HTML через код (в вашем случае это `document.ToHtml()`), кидаете его в блокнот (или что вам удобней) и смотрите, есть ли там нужные данные и где они находятся. Если данных нет, то [анализируете трафик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), смотрите куда сайт идет за всем нужным. Конкретно на этом сайте все данные есть в HTML, просто не под теми тегами, что в браузере.