# Как вписать данные на сайте и нажать кнопку программно?

Tags: python, c#

У меня такая проблема: каждый день на сервере одной игры, в которую я играю, можно заходить и голосовать за сервер, чтобы получать различные бонусы, я решил ради интереса написать программу, которая будет на сайте вписывать в поле для ввода мой никнейм и нажимать кнопку "Голосовать". Да, это колхозно, но на этих сайтах просто на просто нету API, и сделать запросами это невозможно, как это можно реализовать через Python или C#?

Comment: Посмотрите на селениум xD https://www.selenium.dev/ (p.s. каков вопрос таков и совет)

Comment: Запросами сделать почти всё можно. Ну а для простоты да, использовать селениум, по сути тебе 3 метода нужно будет

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553