# C# WebRequest парсинг сайта где данные подгружаются (например Instagram)

Tags: c#, парсер, instagram, httpwebrequest

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как спарсить данные с **Instagram** (Количество подписок, подписчиков, публикации).

Вроде бы у них есть **API**, но он не нужен.

Comment: Берёте и парсите. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Если API не нужен, то и с парсингом проблем не должно быть.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553 P.S. Почитайте документацию про `WebRequest`, увидите там "не рекомендуется для новой разработки", то есть, этот класс устарел и заброшен Microsoft.

Comment: Вначале у instagram есть такая противная подгрузка, и нет никаких элементов. Как ее обойти?

Comment: EvgeniyZ, спасибо. Может через что то другое можно парсинг данных реализовать?