# Как спарсить динамический текст python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

пишу небольшой парсер курсов валют на языке python и библиотеках requests и
beautifulsoup4.

1. Вот [сайт](https://sky.bank/uk/currency) который я хочу спарсить.
2. Вот код парса необходимых мне tr

```
def parse():
    URL = 'http://sky.bank/uk/currency'
    HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'my user agent'
    }
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('tr')
    print(items[1])
    print(items[2])
    print(items[3])
```

Если вызвать данную функцию то будет видно что внутри tr есть 3 тэга  1-валюта, 2-курс покупки, 3-курс продажи. Так же можно увидеть что каждый из курсов покупки имеет в себе цифры 33.6, а каждый из курсов продажи имеет в себе цифры 33.9, но на сайте там совершенно другие цифры, насколько я понимаю, эти данные динамические. Так вот вопрос: ***как корректно спарсить эти цифры?***

Comment: с помощью selenium

Comment: можно выбрать другой сайт

Comment: Почитайте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), поймете, что у сайта есть API, от куда он и берет данные, достаточно отправить POST запрос на этот API и получите все в красивом JSON.

Comment: @Filps - "Если вызвать данную функцию" - Да не обязательно вызывать эту функцию... Достаточно зайти на страничку, которую Вы парсите и выбрать в меню  "Показать исходный код страницы". И там будет видны эти самые 33.6 и 33.9. Так что, проблема не в том, что BeautifulSoup неправильно парсит, а в том, что интерпретируются эти цифирки как-то не так...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ -"у сайта есть API" - Далеко не у всех сайтов есть API. Более того, у подавляющего большинства сайтов его нет. Есть сервисы, содержащие тематические списки сайтов, имеющих API. Например - DaData: https://dadata.ru/api/ Можно порыться там и найти что-то подходящее.

Comment: @Sergey Если сайт динамически получает данные, то у него есть внутренний API, к которому он отсылает запрос, либо соккет, либо еще какой источник данных, с которых он получает это все. Нынче, таких сайтов большинство. Заметьте, я не говорю про публичный API, где идет регистрация, получение доступа, я говорю про нынешние, популярные технологии, которые в первую очередь стоит смотреть, а уж затем искать альтернативы (как посоветовали Вы), либо использовать целые браузеры для получения простых данных (как посоветовал FotonPC).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - "у него есть **внутренний** API". Вы предлагает заняться хакерством? :-)

Comment: @Sergey Если для вас нажатие F12 в браузере, ну или установка софта по типу Fiddler, который покажет все запросы является "хакерством", то ок, давайте будем это называть так. Только в моем понимание "хакерство" - это взлом чего либо, а в данном случае мы лишь пользуемся возможностями сайта напрямую, без рендера HTML и всякого лишнего, без каких либо взломов и др.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У сайта есть API и если, при открытии страницы, посмотреть какие запросы посылает сайт, то найдем такие ссылки:

- GET: https://api.sky.bank/currency/get-offices-list . Возвращает список отделений банков
- POST: https://api.sky.bank/currency/rates-by-codes . Возвращает валюты с значением курса по отделениям банков

Так что, мы можем их повторить.

Кст,:

- Не все сайты имеют данные по валюте, поэтому в API их больше, чем отображается
- Валюта приходит в меньшем номинале (копейки, центы и т.п.), поэтому в ответе есть и указание на сколько делить (см. `buy_unit` и `sell_unit`)
- Делить лучше как `Decimal` (чтобы указать максимальную точность, типа 2 знака после запятой и т.п.), чем `float`, но для простоты решения оставил `float`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1f17e4ad9dc9b58c6f34fda7916583605c2bde2c/html_parsing/api_sky_bank__currency.py#L33)

```
import requests


session = requests.session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'


URL_GET_OFFICES = 'https://api.sky.bank/currency/get-offices-list'
URL_RATES_BY_CODES = 'https://api.sky.bank/currency/rates-by-codes'


rs = session.get(URL_GET_OFFICES)

office_id_by_name = {
    x['id']: x['sname'] for x in rs.json()['response']
}
print(office_id_by_name)
# {24: '1 ФИЛИАЛ (закр)', 2: 'АТ "СКАЙ БАНК"', 25: 'Барвінківське відділення', 4: 'БАРВ.Ф.АКРБ "РЕГ_ОН-БАНК" ...

rs = session.post(URL_RATES_BY_CODES)
currency_by_rates = rs.json()['response']
print(currency_by_rates)
# {'EUR': [{'id': 839871, 'currency_id': 4, 'unit': None, 'rate': None, 'date': '2022-01-28T00:00:00+02:00', ...

print()

for office_id, name in office_id_by_name.items():
    print(f'{name} (#{office_id}):')

    for currency_name, rates in currency_by_rates.items():
        for rate in rates:
            if rate['office_id'] == office_id:
                buy_rate = rate["buy_rate"]
                sell_rate = rate["sell_rate"]
                print(f'    {currency_name}: {buy_rate} | {sell_rate}')

    print()
```

Результат:

```
1 ФИЛИАЛ (закр) (#24):

АТ "СКАЙ БАНК" (#2):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Барвінківське відділення (#25):

БАРВ.Ф.АКРБ "РЕГ_ОН-БАНК",М.БАРВ_НКОВЕ (#4):

Виртуальное ТОБО АТ "СКАЙ БАНК" (#29):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Днепр (#22):

Київське відділення №1 (#21):
    EUR: 32.17 | 32.32
    RUB: 0.361 | 0.37
    USD: 28.82 | 28.9

Ф-Я N 1 АКРБ  "РЕГ_ОН-БАНК",ХАРК_В (#3):

Харківське відділення №1 (#6):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське відділення №11 (#16):

Харківське відділення №12 (#17):

Харківське відділення №13 (#18):

Харківське відділення №14 (#19):

Харківське відділення №2 (#7):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське відділення №3 (#8):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське відділення №4 (#9):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське відділення №5 (#10):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське відділення №7 (#12):

Харківське відділення №8 (#13):

Харківське головне відділення (#14):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

Харківське Центральне відділення (#23):
    EUR: 32.2 | 32.35
    RUB: 0.362 | 0.371
    USD: 28.85 | 28.95

ХВ N10 АТ `РЕГІОН-БАНК` (#15):

ХВ N15 АТ `РЕГІОН-БАНК` (#20):

ХВ N6 АТ `РЕГІОН-БАНК` (#11):

ХФ БАРВЕНКОВО(ЗАКР) (#26):

Чугуев филилал (Закр) (#28):

Чугуївське відділення (#27):

ЧУГУЇВ.Ф.АКРБ "РЕГ_ОН-БАНК", М.ЧУГУЇВ (#5):
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests_html import HTMLSession

ua = UserAgent()
s = HTMLSession()
response = s.get(
    'http://sky.bank/uk/currency',
    headers={
        'User-Agent': ua.chrome
    }
)

response.html.render(
    sleep=2,
    scrolldown=True
)

soup = Soup(response.html.raw_html, 'html.parser')
data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in  soup.find_all('td', {'data-currency': 'EUR'})]
print(data)

# Запускал в течении 5 минут несколько раз. Вывод одинаковый
# Соответствующий данным на сайте
```

Вывод

```latex
['32.20', '32.35']
```