# Как из Powershell запроса сделать C# WebRequest?

Tags: c#, request

Доброй ночи всем, я сейчас пытаюсь сделать получатель и отправлятель сообщений на одном форуме, я полный 0 в этом, никогда не сталкивался с запросами.
Я решил начать с отправки сообщения.

Я отправляю сообщение и смотрю новые запросы в Network (Использую Chrome)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я копирую запрос как для PowerShell и отправлю его в PowerShell, то сообщение отправляется
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать дальше? Есть ли какая-нибудь информация про перевод из Network Chrome в C# запрос?
Я искал информацию про это, но попадается ТОЛЬКО про обычную отправку запросов без упоминания как легко сделать запрос.

Comment: Нужно больше деталей, по двум скринам непонятно, что вам нужно. Например покажите скрипт PS, который получился.

Comment: Как разберетесь с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553), думайте про C#

Comment: @aepot, это json из 8000 символов