# c# парсинг xpath на скриптованной странице

Tags: c#, парсер, xpath

[image: html]Пробую спарсить тэги (div например) на сайте 5-tv.ru . Но в процессе работы программы вместо нормального html внутри скрипты jsные. Как получить готовую разметку и уже ее парсить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924219

Comment: Этот вопрос здесь появляется примерно 2 раза в месяц, такую картину наблюдаю с начала своего присутствия на этом ресурсе. У вас задача достать информацию, которую скрипты добавили на страницу, так? А вы задайтесь вопросом, где они эту информацию берут. Не магическим же образом она спавнится в недрах яваскрипта, а откуда-то приходит, верно? Вот там и берите.