# C# парсинг , отключить Ajax pagination

Tags: c#, ajax, pagination

Собирался сделать для парсер на С# и столкнулся с тем что когда хочу взять все ссылки со страницы - они там не все, потому что остальная часть ссылок прячется за кнопкой **"Load more.."** к примеру вот здесь https://github.com/collections . И кликая на **"Load more..."** url страницы даже не меняется, но новое содержимое для html появляется с которого надо спарсить.

Может кто подскажет каким способом можно получить все ссылки с одной страницы обойдя этот Ajax pagination? или тут одним С# не обойтись?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а пройдя по всем страничкам ссылками типа `/collections/?page=3` не пойдет?

Comment: @Андрюха можно и так да, просто не мог понять где взять эту ссылку которая ведёт на некст страницу

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553