# Python requests. Авторизация на сайте для парсинга оптовых

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, аутентификация, авторизация

Нужно спарсить каталог сайта https://www.xn--80ablb4ac7ci4e.xn--p1ai,
брать название и оптовую цену, которая видна только после авторизации на сайте, весь интернет перерыл, не понимаю как реализовать авторизацию.
пробовал так, но ничего не меняется, вход в аккаунт не происходит, просто получаю html код страницы

```
def authorization(url, mail, password):
with requests.session() as session:
    session.get(url)
    data = {
        "email": mail,
        "password": password
    }

    headers = {
        "User-Agent":user_agent,
        }
    response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
return session
```

Хотелось бы решить это не используя selenium
прошу помогите, срочно!

Comment: Если вы будете так светить свой логин и пароль то точно уже не авторизуетесь.

Comment: Вход в аккаунт тыканьем в небо отличная у вас стратегия. Капчу как при входе собрались обходить?

Comment: Капчи там нет, я попробовал кучу методов, это лишь один из, так что называть это тыканьем в небо у меня язык не поворачивается

Comment: Капча есть если с первого раза не пустило.  POST https://www.xn--80ablb4ac7ci4e.xn--p1ai/client_account/session тело запроса utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=5DIseCTvwfNBTECjJiOLemrpbVTwbQSthJjtJmfwfYZ3Oi1LdfctrpDsbFWcJxFZ3NrV8aIez6zEaXbmwrnsDg%3D%3D&email=sh%40mail.ru&password=weerrttty&commit=

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло! Могли бы вы поподробнее объяснить как вы составляли тело запроса, или направить меня на какой-нибудь ресурс

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333