# Парсинг TripAdvisor

Tags: c#, парсер, xnet

Пытаюсь спарсить список отелей России с https://www.tripadvisor.ru/
Выловил Post запрос, через который получаются данные. Сбор организую с помощью xNet

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
        {
            var reqParams = new RequestParams();

            reqParams["plSeed"] = "574926093";
            reqParams["offset"] = "30";
            reqParams["reqNum"] = "1";
            reqParams["isLastPoll"] = "false";
            reqParams["paramSeqId"] = "1";
            reqParams["waitTime"] = "31";
            reqParams["changeSet"] = "MAIN_META,PAGE_OFFSET";
            reqParams["puid"] = "2a70e7d1-7b26-4568-8964-2f68444b42e4";

            request[HttpHeader.Accept] = "text/html, */*";
            request[HttpHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7";
            request[HttpHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
            request[HttpHeader.Referer] = "https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Hotels-g294459-Russia-Hotels.html";

            string content = request.Post(
                "https://www.tripadvisor.ru/Hotels-g294459-Russia-Hotels.html", reqParams).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(content);
        }
```

Так же нужно передать параметры (они на картинке).
На консоль вывожу html страницу с кодом, для проверки.
*Ошибка: xNet.HttpException: "Не удалось загрузить ответ от HTTP-сервера 'www.tripadvisor.ru'."*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `с помощью xNet` - Чтож все туда лезут я не пойму, уже давно стандартные c# компоненты могут почти все, что умела та библиотека, научитесь ими пользоваться, а затем уже пробуйте сторонние библиотеки. `Не удалось загрузить ответ от HTTP-сервера` - это не ошибка, а просто текст, который говорит "ей, что-то пошло не так!", а вот что пошло не так - скорей всего написано в тексте ошибки, либо во внутренней ошибке, смотрите внимательно туда, тогда скорей всего поймете в чем проблема. [Проанализируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553) сначала сайт, без кода, поймете, что вы забыли Cookie

Comment: Какая именно форма должна быть в запросе? Url-encoded или Multipart? Вы сравнивали что отправляется серверу из кода с тем что отправляется из браузера? Покажите исходники пакетов, заголовки и тело запроса должны по составу данных совпадать. А так у вас вопрос-угадайка.