# Как авторизоваться в телеграм веб при помощи BS4?

Tags: python, telegram, bs4, telethon

Возникла такая проблема, что через API телграмма telethon не удается скопировать пост из канала из-за того, что в канале стоит запрет на копирование. И вот чтобы обойти это ограничение, я не придумал ничего гениальнее, чем сделать свзяку telethon + BS4, где через telethon я получаю id нового сообщения и копирую полностью содержимое этого сообщенмя через веб версию телеграм и т.д. Но чтобы всё это сделать мне нужно авторизоваться на сайте телеграм, вопрос, как это сделать? Я видел что для этого люди в интернете исплользовали requests, ну вот я тоже решил это попробовать, но я не знаю какие данные передать в post запросе серверу, чтобы всё работало. Selenium в этом деле куда проще, но для данной задачи мне нужен иммено BS4.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я наткнуля на такую библиотеку как pyrogram. У неё нет никаких запретов на копирование, и она полностью решает мою проблему.