# Парсер выдает пустой список

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь спарсить авито, но вместо каких-либо данных выводится пустой список, что бы я не писала. Любые классы, любые теги - все равно возвращает пустой список. Что с этим делать? Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.avito.ru/'
html = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('div', class_='body-titleRow-AvL3d')
print(a)
```

Comment: "Что с этим делать?" 1 Забить толстый болт. 2 Искать альтернативные медоты парсинга 3 Использовать Selenium или requests_html. 4 Если чешется сделать через requests учитесь отлавливать запросы.

Comment: а как мне научиться отлавливать запросы? может у вас есть мысли, что почитать на эту тему?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333 https://hackware.ru/?p=7641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы просто распечатаете html, который прилетает в ответ на запрос, в терминале, вы увидите следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и, соответственно, если сохраните тот же код в файл, то увидите вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, если вы будете заходить на авито через обычный браузер, то увидите, что все в порядке. Получается, что авито распознает в ваших запросах автоматические, даже если вы установите заголовки и куки, ответ будет один и тот же.

Но можно использовать selenium, про который писали в комментариях. Для этого, его надо установить с помощью pip, выполнив команду: 
pip install selenium.

Затем, вам нужно будет скачать веб-драйвер для вашей операционной системы, для примера, драйвер для Chrome, вот [отсюда](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Подробнее, вы сможете прочитать об этом на странице самого [проекта](https://www.selenium.dev/).

И установить браузер Google Chrome, если он у вас еще не установлен (для примера).

Ну и вот вам небольшой пример, в котором используется загрузка страницы с авито.

```
import os
import time
from platform import system

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium_stealth import stealth

options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

executable_path = None

if system() == "Windows":
    executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver', 'chromedriver.exe')
elif system() == "Linux":
    executable_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver', 'chromedriver')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(log_path=os.devnull, executable_path=executable_path))

stealth(driver=browser,
        user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                   'Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36',
        languages=["ru-RU", "ru"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        run_on_insecure_origins=True,
        )

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
a = soup.find_all('div', class_='body-titleRow-AvL3d')
print(a)

browser.quit()
```

Что здесь происходит? Загружается браузер в, так называемом, стелс-режиме, который помогает скрывать то, что браузером управляет автоматизированное ПО. Однако, не всегда и не на всех сайтах. Затем браузеру устанавливаются определенные опции. Выполняется переход на страницу Авито, загружается страница, а потом я использовал ваш код, только загрузил туда те результаты, что были получены браузером. И теперь, тот тег, что вы искали, был успешно найден.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что, да, для таких сайтов, как Авито, с динамическим контентом и защитой от разного рода парсеров и скреперов, можно использовать selenium.

**UPD:** Забыл упомянуть, что драйвер должен лежать, в данном примере, в папке "chromedriver", в директории проекта.

Надеюсь, что мое объяснение вам немного помогло.

Comment: спасибо огромное! очень полезно!