# не парсится часть данных, python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

На странице 100 данных необходимых для парсинга.
Парсить пробую:

1. Название кроптовалюты (парсится 10 из 100, а остальные попадают в блок except)
2. Акроним (парсится 10 из 100, а остальные попадают в блок except)
3. Ссылку (парсится 100 из 100)
4. Стоимость (парсится 100 из 100)

Страница которую пробую парсить: https://coinmarketcap.com/
Код у 10 и 11 элемента не отличается, поэтому не понимаю в чем проблема.
Напроимер 2 куска кода откуда я пытаюсь вытащить название криптовалюты:
Dogecoin - пасится,
Polkadot - не парсится

```html
<div display="flex" class="sc-16r8icm-0 escjiH">
  <a href="/currencies/dogecoin/" class="cmc-link">
    <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-0 dBKWCw">
      <img class="coin-logo" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/74.png" loading="lazy" alt="DOGE logo">
        <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 dNOTPP">
           <p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT">Dogecoin</p>
          <div data-nosnippet="true" class="sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI">
            <div class="sc-1teo54s-3 etWhyV">10</div>
              <p color="text3" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol" font-size="1">DOGE</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>


<div display="flex" class="sc-16r8icm-0 escjiH">
  <a href="/currencies/polkadot-new/" class="cmc-link">
    <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-0 dBKWCw">
      <img class="coin-logo" src="https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/6636.png" loading="lazy" alt="DOT logo">
        <div class="sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1teo54s-1 dNOTPP">
          <p font-weight="semibold" color="text" font-size="1" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT">Polkadot</p>
            <div data-nosnippet="true" class="sc-1teo54s-2 fZIJcI">
              <div class="sc-1teo54s-3 etWhyV">11</div>
                <p color="text3" class="sc-1eb5slv-0 gGIpIK coin-item-symbol" font-size="1">DOT</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Мой код:

```html
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    tablerows = soup.find('table', class_='cmc-table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')

    for tablerow in tablerows:
        td = tablerow.find_all('td') 
        try:
            name = td[2].find('div', class_='dNOTPP').find('p').text
        except:
            name=''

        try:
            symbol = td[2].find('p', class_='coin-item-symbol').text
        except:
            symbol=''

        try:
            url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com'+td[2].find('a').get('href')
        except:
            url=''

        try:
            price = td[3].find('span').text
        except:
            price=''

        #словарь
        data={'name':name, 'symbol':symbol , 'url':url, 'price':price}

        write_csv(data)
        print(name)
```

Comment: Динамический сайт. 10 позиций в HTML, а остальные JS дорисовал

Comment: Учимся отлавливать запросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333 или используем селенимум