# Не авторизовывает на сайте, хотя ответ <Response [200]>

Tags: python, requests, авторизация

Скрипт должен просто авторизоваться на сайте и все, с чем я уже 3-ий день не могу справиться

```
import requests

data = {
    'login':'da@gmail.com',
    'password':'da'
}

header = {
    'user-agent':''
}

link = "http://lolz.guru/login/"
s = requests.Session()

response = requests.post(link, data=data, headers=header)
print(response)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Comment: Добрый день. На сайте форма или basic/digital аутентификация?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @DavidusCorvus привет, там нужен при авторизации только пароль и логин, все.

Answer (score 0):

Во многих проектах уже реализованы удобные API. Вы можете буквально за одно строку авторизовываться и взаимодействовать. Всегда гуглите API перед тем, что бы создавать свой велосипед. Вот вам ссылочки:[API documentation](https://github.com/NztForum/Lolzteam-Public-API/blob/master/docs/api.markdown), [Example](https://github.com/xALEGORx/LolzApi/blob/master/example_check_payment.py), [LOLZTEAM API DOC](https://lolz.guru/threads/2370826/)