# Парсинг данных get запрос

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Ситуация следующая. Я сделал код для парсинга данных с сайта с помощью `requests` и запросом `get` данный запрос имеет `headers` и там передает `cookies`.

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, пока я нахожусь с браузера в аккаунте под учетной записью, `код 200`, как только нажму в браузере на кнопку `выход` или выключу комп, `код 400 bad request`. Кто подскажет как обойти данную проблему?

P.S. пока пробовал, получилось обойти проблему вот таким образом:

```
data = {
    'login':'login',
    'pass':'password'
}

headers = {
     ......
}

params = {
     .......
}

p = requests.post('url', headers=headers, data=data)
print(p)
r = requests.get('url', headers=headers,params=params)
print(r)
```

Если кто предложит как правильнее записать буду рад)

Comment: Кусок кода хотя-бы в студию:)

Comment: Попробовал перед запросом get сделать запрос post с данными по авторизации. Пока вроде прокатило)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Comment: @СергейШ я это все сделал, проблема в том, что перед get запросом похоже нужно делать post запрос с данными авторизации. причем всегда делать, иначе get не проходит

Comment: А как по вашему в браузере сайт запоминает что это вы, как вы думаете?

Comment: @СергейШ проблема в том, что если данные Data передавать через get запрос то ничего не происходит. поэтому вижу только один выход, сначала передать post а потом get