# Можно ли вывести значения элементов страницы, если информация только в личной кабинете?

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хотел сделать парсер для вывода информации со школьного сайта, но BeautifulSoap не может найти элемент кода.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = str("https://gimn3.eljur.ru/journal-app?user=vov-em&domain=gimn3")

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

#Find
text_orig = soup.findAll('a', class_='b-href')
text = str(text_orig[0])
print(text)
```

[image: Скрин кода элемента сайта, откуда я беру информацию]

Вывод `text`: `<div class="logo__title">МБОУ Гимназия №3</div>`

Тут всё нормально, но если зайти в аккаунт, то код не может найти элементы страницы

```
text_orig = soup.findAll('div', class_='dnevnik-day__title')
text = str(text_orig[0])
print(text)
```

[image: Скрин кода элемента сайта, откуда я хожу вывести информацию]

Вывод:
[image: Ошибка, которая вылезает]

Не уверен, что вся эта информация будет полезна, но решил максимально подробно всё объяснить.

*И я понимаю, что ошибка в том, что в массиве нет значений.*

Можно ли как-то зайти в свой аккаунт на сайте в BeautifulSoap или получать код элемента со страницы из моего браузера(даже если с запущенного браузера)?

Comment: "Можно ли как-то зайти в свой аккаунт на сайте в BeautifulSoap" нет не возможно, но можно через requests  для этого потребуются дополнительные знания на этом ресурсе есть небольшой гайд. "получать код элемента со страницы из моего браузера" можно через селенимум.

Comment: Добрый день. Могли бы указать ссылку на этот гайд, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333