# Как получить cookie из приложения Steam?

Tags: python, cookie, steam

Ищу отрывок кода просто с получением куки, мне это нужно для полноценного скрипта, но я не понимаю как это сделать, но знаю что их получить можно, так как само приложение Steam является браузером и использует их для работы.

Единственный вариант который работает, это открытие браузера в стиме через BigPicture, открытие в нём консоли разработчика и копирование куки, но это занимает слишком много времени. Язык - Python.

Comment: Сколько заплатите за это?

Comment: Зачем именно приложение ковырять? Откройте стим просто в браузере, залогиньтесь, возьмите куки оттуда.

Comment: С таким вопрос лучше пойти на фри-ланс  биржу и сделать заказ
Тут помогают с уже готовым кодом при возникновении ошибок, а не пишут с нуля

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333