# Сайт Wildberries загружается по-разному

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Проблема заключается в следующем. Я пытаюсь получить данные со страницы карточки товара в WB. Делаю это с помощью Selenium chrome driver и Python. Однако, когда я впервые открываю ссылку на товар методом .get() драйвера - он загружает одну структуру сайта. Когда загружаю следующую ссылку не закрывая при этом браузера - загружается другая структура html кода и поэтому скрипт сыплется.
Думал cookie виновны - попробовал сохранять - не помогло. Возможно кеш какой-то сохраняется. Но как его очищать и вообще почему сайт грузится по разному. Я понимаю, что есть Ajax, но ведь и он должен отрабатывать одинаково. А в чем прикол не пойму. К чему он привязывается…

Comment: Узнал, что WB использует client site rendering. Надо смотреть api запросы и по Нил работать. Как это делать?

Comment: Забавно конечно наблюдать, как люди используют "танк" в виде целого браузера, для того, чтоб просто получить текст... Вот зачем вам тут селениум и HTML? Вам надо UI спарсить, кнопочки "показать", "купить", их цвет, и так далее, или всеж данные? Если данные, то может стоит найти источник этих данных и с ним работать? Нынче почти любой современный сайт использует API, или соккеты, где сам сайт запрашивает у сервера данные, ну и указанный вами сайт [не исключение](https://basket-10.wb.ru/vol1463/part146353/146353690/info/ru/card.json). [Для изучения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553).