# Не удается получить данные с сайта

Tags: python, html5, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер для сайта https://www.shibor.org/shibor/dataservicesen/

Необходимо получить данные с фрейма Shibor

Имеется код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL  = 'https://www.shibor.org/shibor/dataservicesen/'

HEADERS = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"}

def get_html(url):
    return requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)

def get_content_iframe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pattern = r'(src=\"/[A-za-z/\-\.]+shibor\-def\-down\-iframe\-e\.html\")'
    src = re.search(pattern, str(soup))
    new_url = 'https://www.shibor.org' + src[0].split('"')[1]
    html_new = get_html(new_url)
    new_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_new.text, 'html.parser')
    return new_soup

def parser(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        return get_content_iframe(html.text)
    else:
        return None

new_soup = parser(URL)
qw = new_soup.find('div', id_="page-shibor-history")
print(qw)
```

Но в ответе получаю None, хотя если просматривать html такой тег с таким id существует.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо получить данные из этой таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вместо requests использовать селенимум или requests_html то может быть ваш код и заработает )). Или на прямую используя API сайта https://www.shibor.org/ags/ms/cm-u-bk-shibor/ShiborHis?lang=en&startDate=27%20May%202023&endDate=26%20Jun%202023

Comment: вот еше интересная ссылка https://www.shibor.org/dqs/rest/cm-u-bk-shibor/ShiborHisExcel?lang=en&startDate=27%20May%202023&endDate=26%20Jun%202023

Comment: @СергейШ, вариант с API сработал, но я никак не могу найти к нему документацию. можете пожалуйста скинуть ссылку?

Comment: Я тоже не нашёл)) Проанализировал запросы между браузером и сайтом. почитать на досуге https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Answer (score 0):

вам нужно использовать

```py
find('div', id="page-shibor-history")
```

а не

```py
find('div', id_="page-shibor-history")
```

вот рабочий код можете его проанализировать.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = 'https://www.shibor.org/shibor/dataservicesen/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"}

def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response
    else:
        print(response.status_code)

def get_content_iframe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    pattern = r'(src=\"/[A-za-z/\-\.]+shibor\-def\-down\-iframe\-e\.html\")'
    src = re.search(pattern, str(soup))
    new_url = 'https://www.shibor.org' + src[0].split('"')[1]
    response = get_html(new_url)
    return response

def parser(url):
    response = get_html(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return get_content_iframe(response)
    else:
        print(response.status_code)

def main():
    html = parser(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    qw = soup.find('div', id="page-shibor-history")
    print(qw)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Так как сайт использует js для загрузги сайта будем использовать playwright

Устанавливаем playwright

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

Вот обнов код

```
import requests
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re



URL = 'https://www.shibor.org/shibor/dataservicesen/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"}

def get_html(url):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.set_default_timeout(0)
        page.goto(url)
        page.wait_for_selector("div[id='shibor-his-cn']")
        return page.content()


def get_content_iframe(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    pattern = r'(src=\"/[A-za-z/\-\.]+shibor\-def\-down\-iframe\-e\.html\")'
    src = re.search(pattern, str(soup))
    new_url = 'https://www.shibor.org' + src[0].split('"')[1]
    response = get_html(new_url)
    return response

def parser(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return get_content_iframe(response)
    else:
        print(response.status_code)

def main():
    html = parser(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    qw = soup.find('div', id="page-shibor-history")
    print(qw)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: спасибо, код работает, но не выводит данные самой таблицы с этого сайта

Comment: Вам  нужно испозовать https://pypi.org/project/splash/

Comment: или же playwright, будет проще.

Comment: Обновил код посмотрите.