# Почему requests не возвращает информацию которую я вижу в браузере?

Tags: python, requests

При переходе по адресу в браузере (адрес изменен):

> https://domain.ru/old_api/old_presence?login_list=userlogin

Получаю пустую страницу с единственной строкой:

> {"result": true, "staff": {"userlogin": {"is_available": false}}}

Но при выполнении кода ниже:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'Authorization':  <мой токен>}
response = requests.post('https://domain.ru/old_api/old_presence?login_list=userlogin', headers=headers)
print(response.json())
```

Никак не могу получить на выход эту строку чтобы ее распарсить. Вот это все не помогает:

```
print(response.json())
print(response.text)
print(response.content)
```

Что сделать чтобы скрипт получил в ответ именно эту строку которую я вижу в браузере?

Comment: Для начала переход по адресу это get, а вы почему-то отправляете post

Comment: Если вы не заполнили ВСЕ заголовки запроса как это сделал браузер, то не можете гарантировать, что ответ будет такой же :)
Например, встречались мне сервера, что ругались, если User-Agent был не тот, что они ожидали

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный лог респонса то что видно в браузере во вкладке dev tools network

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333