# Парсинг магазина "Лента" на Python

Tags: python, requests, веб-скрейпинг

Мне нужно спарсить товары по скидке в магазине "Лента" https://lenta.com/promo/. Я смог найти api https://lenta.com/api/v1/skus/list... . Добавил к этой ссылке payload. При post запросе получаю такой ответ:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
<script src="/__qrator/qauth_utm_v2.js"></script>
```

Попытался с помощью postman добавть headers, но не помогло.Данные запроса выглядили так(Cookie полностью скопировал из request headers):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете объяснить новичку, что не так.

Comment: Запросы - это не только заголовки. Запросы - это совокупность нескольких факторов: 1. Тип запроса. 2. Заголовок. 3. Тело. Все эти пункты имеют разные "подпункты", где тип может быть POST/GET/PUT и прочее; заголовок это тип контента, его вес, агент браузера, куки, хост, реферер, и прочее; ну а тело, это либо форма, либо json/xml и пр, либо данные в строки, ну и так далее. Вот чтоб ваш запрос дал вам нужное, вы должны найти то, что требует сервер, все это получить, и отправить.

Comment: Конкретный сайт требует отправку POST запроса с JSON телом на адрес `/api/v1/skus/list`. В заголовках должно быть обязательно [3 Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hppJo.png) и установленный `User-Agent`. Вот собственно и изучайте дальше запросы, смотрите от куда сайт получает все эти значения, и как их получить програмно. Распутаете этот клубок - получите нужное.

Comment: Можете рассказать, где  узнать, какие именно Cokkie нужны для опредлённого. сайта

Comment: Postmen вам в помощь. Заносите в него прям копию запроса из браузера, а дальше поочередно удаляете лишние данные, смотря на ответ, таким перебором узнаете то, что конкретно влияет на данный запрос, что он требует. Об этом я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553).

Comment: Странно, я использовал его,как вы и написали. Переписал все данные из request headers и из payload  запроса на сайте, но у меня  ничего не получалось(я получал в ответ код из самого начала)

Comment: Не все значит переписали. Я лично проверил, скопировал Cookie, заголовки, и получил копию ответа от сайта. Для того, чтоб сайт выдавал в ответ JSON, достаточно валидной `qrator_jsid`, но данных там не будет, будет JSON с пустыми значениями, ну а вот чтоб эти значения там появились, нужно 2 оставшиеся Cookie.

Comment: Я не очень понял разницы ваших действий с моими. Не могли бы вы посмотреть на скринах, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Cookie в соответствующий раздел вставьте (под кнопкой Send), а не в заголовок, ну и UserAgent по умолчанию Postman свой ставит, этого достаточно. Ну и внимательно копируйте значения Cookie. Вот вам мои скрины: [тело](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gduW6.png), [заголовки (скрытые не трогал, там есть UserAgent)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ01g.png), ну и [Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgVw6.png). Как видите, сервер мне отдает успешно все данные. Сами Cookie я просто копировал вручную, через несколько попыток надоело, включил синхронизацию с браузера, после чего удалял лишние.