# Как сделать запрос в requests если на сайте в блоке нету name

Tags: python, requests

Хочу сделать запрос на сайт (Войти в аккаунт) но там в инпутах логина и пароля нету name и я не понимаю как сделать `post` запрос без `name`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

s=requests.session()

aut={
    'Name':'login',
    'Name': 'password'
}

URL_TEMPLATE = "https://twofish.cc/login"
r = requests.post(URL_TEMPLATE,aut)


print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

> Ошибка: 400 (Не верно заданы параметры)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Comment: У Вас в словаре aut два одинаковых ключа 'name'.

Comment: Я про то что тут должный стоять имена блоков но их нету что бы было понятно я вставил Name