# Парсинг значения с сайта https://steam-currency.ru/

Tags: python, парсер

Пытаюсь получить значение курса доллара с сайта https://steam-currency.ru/.
Но beatifulSoup не видит теги в дереве дальше `<div id="root">`, то есть по его мнению этот тег не содержит ничего. Как понять почему?

```
def get_rate_USDRUB():
    html = requests.get(f'https://steam-currency.ru').content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    div = soup.find('div', class_='CurrentCourse_Wrapper__e-MAR')
    return div
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://api.steam-currency.ru/currency/USD:RUB

Comment: Спасибо. Это даже лучше. Но как вы до этого додумались?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9