# Как с помощью requests в python получить ту же версию сайта, что и для Chrome?

Tags: python, html, requests, pycharm

Есть сайт https://timetable.spbu.ru/
Когда мы открываем его в Chrome, мы получаем версию на русском языке. В консоли разработчика конструкция, отвечающая за переключение языка, выглядит так:

```
<input class="locale-option" name="clientCultureName" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio">
<input class="locale-option" name="clientCultureName" id="ru" value="ru" type="radio" checked="checked">
```

Когда мы получаем его в PyCharm с помощью кода

```
import requests
a = requests.get('https://timetable.spbu.ru')
print(a.text)
```

Мы видим версию на английском языке, та же самая конструкция теперь выглядит так:

```
<input class="locale-option" name="clientCultureName" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio"         checked="checked"
 />
<input class="locale-option" name="clientCultureName" id="ru" value="ru" type="radio"  />
```

Также стоит добавить, что переключатель языка на сайте сломан, и если мы в Chrome перейдём на английский, то на русский вернуться уже не сможем, не очистив кэш. В мобильной версии не помогает и это, сайт застревает в английском.
Итак, в чём может быть проблема и как получить в PyCharm русскую версию?

Comment: что такое «crome»?

Comment: "Chrome" конечно же, опечатка

Comment: так исправьте, нажав [edit]

Comment: Merci, не мог найти эту кнопку, теперь готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
}

response = requests.get('https://timetable.spbu.ru/', headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает! Подскажите, как лучше загуглить или какие посмотреть источники, чтобы подробнее разодраться в этой теме?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333