# ошибка requests, post запрос

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests

params = {"phone": "998946282712", "name": "magnatik", "group": 2472}

reqston = requests.post("https://smstel.ru/api/create/contact?key=1dddad9226dd4f4fd4018afc4022457b6c715e87", params=params)
print(reqston.text)
```

Ошибка:
{"status":400,"message":"Invalid Request","data":false}

Comment: У вас запрос не прошёл некую валидацию.

Comment: А просто через браузер пробовали? Соберите ссылку ручками и проверьте ответ.

Comment: [400](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#400)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924219/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9

Comment: да пробовал @Amgarak

Comment: @Magnat и как работало?

Comment: нет сработало, @Amgarak помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @Magnat если сработало, то добавьте рабочею ссылку в свой вопрос, а дальше посмотрим 

Comment: *не сработало @Amgarak

Comment: @Magnat читайте тогда документацию по вашему API, как то не правильно собираете ссылку может ваш ключ не работает, не знаю.