# Как узнать API сайта

Tags: c#, html, веб-программирование, htmlagilitypack, веб-скрейпинг

я только начал изучать тему парсинга, сейчас я учусь этому на c#. и я узнал, что для моей цели(парсинг сайтов банков) подходит API. как его узнать и получить?

Comment: Если на сайте нет раздела API - то, значит, его нет.......На крайняк: заходишь на сайт, открываешь контакты, связваешься по ним с людьми и спрашиваешь.... Логично?

Comment: кроме социальной инженерии можно еще попробовать реверсную инженерию

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Comment: А как по итогу этот api узнать и получить, просто я не очень понял)

Comment: [Вот так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565216/#comment2820555_1565216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто загуглить. В большинстве случаев, если API имеется, то для него есть отдельная страница с документацией в общем доступе. Там же и будет рассказано, как получить ключ (если он нужен) к API. Ещё есть вариант, что доступ к API и документации дадут только после официального запроса на почту/телефонного звонка