# Не могу повторить запрос браузера через python requests

Tags: python-3.x, requests, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть pickle файл а сохранённым списком запросов из браузера, захваченных с помощью библиотеки selenium-wire. Я хочу воспроизвести эти запросы к API серверу через requests.Session, я копировал headers и cookies, но это безуспешно, сервер все равно выдовал капчу. Как мне это исправить, чтобы я мог обращаться к серверу через requests.Session?

Если быть конкретнее, это сайт https://store.standoff2.com на странице с вводом промокодов я посмотрел, и обнаружил, что запрос отправляется на https://store.standoff2.com/api/v1/coupon с данными {uid: Id_пользователя, coupon: промокод}.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/470333

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: Сергей Ш, спасибо за помощь, но это не то, что мне нужно