# Ошибка в парсере сайта на C#. Запускаю код в VS Studio с использованием HtmlAgilityPack, ошибка 'Expression must evaluate to a node-set.' Помогите

Tags: c#, html, парсер, htmlagilitypack, c#-8.0

Помогите, пожалуйста, как правильно указать путь к html-классам сайта? (Хочу запарсить все таблицы с названиями команд и отдельно с коэффициентами. Уже месяц пытаюсь, не могу и не знаю как правильно указать путь к таблицам (46, 51, 54, 57, 63 строки) Если что, ссылка на сам сайт: https://parisportif.pmu.fr/home/wrapper/dashboard?lang=fr&activeSportId=1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace cSharpWebParserV04
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> result12 = Parsing12(url12: "https://parisportif.pmu.fr/");
            
            if (result12 != null)
            {
                foreach (var item12 in result12)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine(item12.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    item12.Value.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", r)));
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------\n");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> Parsing12(string url12)
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>> result1 = new Dictionary<string, List<List<string>>>();
                using (HttpClientHandler hdl = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false, AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.None })
                {
                    using (var clnt = new HttpClient(hdl))
                    {
                        using (HttpResponseMessage resp = clnt.GetAsync(url12).Result)
                        {
                            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var html = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
                                {
                                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                                    doc.LoadHtml(html);
                                    var tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='sb-event-list__main']//div[@class='sb-event-list__container']//div[@class]//");// ЗАМЕНИТЬ КЛАСС
                                    if (tables != null && tables.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        foreach (var table in tables)
                                        {
                                            var titleNode = table.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='ng-star-inserted']");
                                            if (titleNode != null)
                                            {
                                                var tbl = table.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='ng-star-inserted']//table");
                                                if (tbl != null)
                                                {
                                                    var rows = tbl.SelectNodes(".//ss-events-list-event");
                                                    if (rows != null && rows.Count > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        var res = new List<List<string>>();
                                                        foreach (var row in rows)
                                                        {
                                                            var cells = row.SelectNodes(".//span");
                                                            if (cells != null && cells.Count > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                res.Add(new List<string>(cells.Select(c => c.InnerText)));
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        result1[titleNode.InnerText] = res;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return result1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("No tables");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Версия .NET какая? _46, 51, 54, 57, 63 строки_ - это где? К каким именно таблицам? В чём заключается задача? На сайте нет ничего из классов, указанных в вашем коде. Вы хоть видели HTML, который отдаёт сайт? `Console.WriteLine(html);` - там вообще нет таблиц. Почему пытаетесь искать в нём то, чего нет в принципе? Смотрите логи браузера, откуда берутся данные, HtmlAgilityPack не нужен здесь вообще https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9LMa.png Нужно получить и распарсить JSON файлы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/924276/220553